# How to fix TS2322: "could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'object'"?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

A have a type-check error in recursive types.

I am trying to write types for react-jss styles object.

```ts
type StylesFn<P extends object> = (
  props: P
) => CSS.Properties<JssValue<P>> | number | string;

type JssValue<P extends object> =
  | string
  | number
  | Array<string | number>
  | StylesFn<P>;

// @ts-ignore
interface StylesObject<K extends string = any, P extends object = {}>
  extends Styles {
  [x: string]: CSS.Properties<JssValue<P>> | Styles<K, P>;
}
export type Styles<K extends string = any, P extends object = {}> = {
  [x in K]: CSS.Properties<JssValue<P>> | StylesObject<any, P> | StylesFn<P>
};
```

It works fine, but typescript writes an error. I use `@ts-ignore`, but this is not fancy

```ts
ERROR 24:11  typecheck  Interface 'StylesObject<K, P>' incorrectly extends interface 'Styles<any, {}>'.
  Index signatures are incompatible.
    Type 'Properties<JssValue<P>> | Styles<K, P>' is not assignable to type 'StylesFn<{}> | Properties<JssValue<{}>> | StylesObject<any, {}>'.
      Type 'Properties<JssValue<P>>' is not assignable to type 'StylesFn<{}> | Properties<JssValue<{}>> | StylesObject<any, {}>'.
        Type 'Properties<JssValue<P>>' is not assignable to type 'Properties<JssValue<{}>>'.
          Type 'JssValue<P>' is not assignable to type 'JssValue<{}>'.
            Type 'StylesFn<P>' is not assignable to type 'JssValue<{}>'.
              Type 'StylesFn<P>' is not assignable to type 'StylesFn<{}>'.
                Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'P'.
                  '{}' is assignable to the constraint of type 'P', but 'P' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'object'.
```

What does this error mean?

Comment: It's the same error message as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56675333/49942) which might be partially answered by comments.

Answer (score 505):

Complementing @fetzz great answer.

---

## **SHORT ANSWER**

**TLDR;** There are two common causes for this kind of error message. You are doing the first one (see below). Along with the text, I explain in rich detail what this error message wants to convey.

**CAUSE 1:** In typescript, a concrete instance is not allowed to be assigned to a type parameter. Following you can see an example of the 'problem' and the 'problem solved', so you can compare the difference and see what changes:

*PROBLEM*

```js
const func1 = <A extends string>(a: A = 'foo') => `hello!` // Error!

const func2 = <A extends string>(a: A) => {
    //stuff
    a = `foo`  // Error!
    //stuff
}
```

*SOLUTION*

```js
const func1 = <A extends string>(a: A) => `hello!` // ok

const func2 = <A extends string>(a: A) => { //ok
    //stuff
    //stuff
}
```

*See in: [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/PTAEF5K6dv4YyAoEoDCBBAqgZQKKgCMqYS5FlcypoAtA40887QAoBKA8gEIAy+ALK0Wo0TQDGAewB2AZwAuoAGYBXGRKJEIoADyZQAUwAeCwzIAmc0IoBOASxkBzAHwAKAIYAuUAfCgAcmUpKQCASggXUAADAAtDABsEqQBCaNA0fFtbKVsUyVlFFXUJACZtf30jU3MrGwUHZ3dvXwjwKIBvZFAejOBFVWVlbt6PHWjgqXS+0CycvJGekAGh5ABfGjQxbcZaXC4+bAAVAEkuADkRHe2C+SU1DSJSnSqTM0trO0dXTx9MNqicUSyTSMykAGtbkUHmVnpUDG9ap8Gt9mn8AaAOn0IYs+ithr08QpBsMNsggA)*

**CAUSE 2:** Although you are not doing the below error in your code. It is also a normal circumstance where this kind of error message pops up. You should avoid doing this:

*Repeat (by mistaken) the `Type Parameter` in a class, type, or interface.*

Don't let the complexity of the below code confuse you, the only thing I want you to concentrate on is how the removing of the letter 'A' solves the problem:

*PROBLEM:*

```js
type Foo<A> = {
    //look the above 'A' is conflicting with the below 'A'
    map: <A,B>(f: (_: A) => B) => Foo<B>
}

const makeFoo = <A>(a: A): Foo<A> => ({
   map: f => makeFoo(f(a)) //error!
})
```

*SOLUTION:*

```js
type Foo<A> = {
    // conflict removed
    map: <B>(f: (_: A) => B) => Foo<B>
}

const makeFoo = <A>(a: A): Foo<A> => ({
   map: f => makeFoo(f(a)) //ok
})
```

*See in: [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/PTAEF5K6dv4YyAoEoDCBBAqgZQKKgBMqYS5FlcypoAtA40887QAoBKA8gEIAy+ALK0Wo0TQAuATwAOAU1AAxAPbKAjAB5MAPgigA3slDHQIADaqA1qAkALBQEMARsoBuCgOSYPoAJYBnUABjZQA7ADMzXyCJX1CAc1AAd187G3tQJzkLJNAvDyMTAFsHGQAuUC0AGh5tAApwirqAfQrMAEoIXR5O8F0VdQ1a5ABfGhDQ-wlQEss5AbU9LXqHNvaKheWu0DrDYtKK8O3Z+dU1BrqHds6QOQAnO+U7gEJR9po0MS-GWlwuPmwABUAJJcAByIm+X0ksgUAyIW3ABkKxjQE0i0WmdzkRTccgAJiiZgdKrUGk1WqAOtsett4UNtKNxmEpsS5vCljpLmsNqoETptrsUSVyqAjn02adlEQLlcbsBlJY3kA)*

---

## **LONG ANSWER**

---

## **UNDERSTANDING THE ERROR MESSAGE**

Following I'll decompose each element of the error message below:

```
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'P'.
  '{}' is assignable to the constraint of type 'P', but 'P' could be
 instantiated with a different subtype of constraint'object'
```

---

### **WHAT IS TYPE `{}`**

It's a type that you can assign anything except null or undefined. For example:

```js
type A = {}
const a0: A = undefined // error
const a1: A = null // error
const a2: A = 2 // ok
const a3: A = 'hello world' //ok
const a4: A = { foo: 'bar' } //ok
// and so on...
```

*See in: [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeBfAUAYwPYDsDOwUAhgAwBcsCUArjgCYQBmAljhHVAPSdQQBOfLH0y4CxAIwU4iHNQA2crj36Dh2fISIAmKVS1KoWANYiNxAMy7EAcgAWEBVigB3IXLrWlx02KIAWK2QoRiwsCmsAIyI+TxQvE3VfAFZAgAoASgQAPhp6JlZ2eLRikqA)*

---

### **WHAT IS `is not assignable`**

*To assign* is to make a variable of a particular type correspond to a particular instance. If you mismatch the type of the instance you get an error. For example:

```js
// type string is not assignable to type number 
const a: number = 'hello world' //error

// type number is assinable to type number
const b: number = 2 // ok
```

---

### **WHAT IS A `different subtype`**

**Two types are equals**: if they do not add or remove details in relation to each other.

**Two types are different**: if they are not equal.

**Type `A` is a subtype of type `S`**: if `A` adds detail *without* removing already existent detail from `S`.

**type `A` and type `B` are different subtypes of type `S`**: If `A` and `B` are subtypes of `S`, but `A` and `B` are different types. Said in other words: `A` and `B` adds detail to the type `S`, *but they do not add the same detail*.

*Example:* In the code below, all the following statements are true:

1. A and D are equal types
2. B is subtype of A
3. E is not subtype of A
4. B and C are different subtype of A

```js
type A = { readonly 0: '0'}
type B = { readonly 0: '0', readonly foo: 'foo'}
type C = { readonly 0: '0', readonly bar: 'bar'}
type D = { readonly 0: '0'}
type E = { readonly 1: '1', readonly bar: 'bar'}
```

```js
type A = number
type B = 2
type C = 7
type D = number
type E = `hello world`
```

```js
type A = boolean
type B = true
type C = false
type D = boolean
type E = number
```

> **NOTE**:  **[Structural Type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system)**
>
> When you see in TS the use of `type` keyword, for instance in `type A = { foo: 'Bar' }` you should read: *Type alias `A` is pointing to type structure `{ foo: 'Bar' }`*.
>
> The general syntax is: `type [type_alias_name] = [type_structure]`.
>
> Typescript type system just checks against `[type_structure]` and not against the `[type_alias_name]`. That means that in TS there's no difference in terms of type checking between following: `type A = { foo: 'bar }` and `type B = { foo: 'bar' }`. For more see: [Official Doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html).

---

### WHAT IS `constraint of type` 'X'

The *Type Constraint* is simply what you put on the right side of the 'extends' keyword. In the below example, the `Type Constraint` is 'B'.

```js
const func = <A extends B>(a: A) => `hello!`
```

Reads: *Type Constraint 'B' is the `constraint of type 'A'`*

---

### **WHY THE ERROR HAPPENS**

To illustrate I'll show you three cases. The only thing that will vary in each case is the `Type Constraint`, nothing else will change.

What I want you to notice is that the restriction that `Type Constraint` imposes to `Type Parameter` *does not include different subtypes*. Let's see it:

Given:

```js
type Foo         =  { readonly 0: '0'}
type SubType     =  { readonly 0: '0', readonly a: 'a'}
type DiffSubType =  { readonly 0: '0', readonly b: 'b'}

const foo:             Foo         = { 0: '0'}
const foo_SubType:     SubType     = { 0: '0', a: 'a' }
const foo_DiffSubType: DiffSubType = { 0: '0', b: 'b' }
```

CASE 1: **NO RESTRICTION**

```js
const func = <A>(a: A) => `hello!`

// call examples
const c0 = func(undefined) // ok
const c1 = func(null) // ok
const c2 = func(() => undefined) // ok
const c3 = func(10) // ok
const c4 = func(`hi`) // ok
const c5 = func({}) //ok
const c6 = func(foo) // ok
const c7 = func(foo_SubType) //ok
const c8 = func(foo_DiffSubType) //ok
```

CASE 2: **SOME RESTRICTION**

Note below that restriction does not affect subtypes.

> **VERY IMPORTANT**: In Typescript the `Type Constraint` *does not restrict different subtypes*

```js
const func = <A extends Foo>(a: A) => `hello!`

// call examples
const c0 = func(undefined) // error
const c1 = func(null) // error
const c2 = func(() => undefined) // error
const c3 = func(10) // error
const c4 = func(`hi`) // error
const c5 = func({}) // error
const c6 = func(foo) // ok
const c7 = func(foo_SubType) // ok  <-- Allowed
const c8 = func(foo_DiffSubType) // ok <-- Allowed
```

CASE 3: **MORE CONSTRAINED**

```js
const func = <A extends SubType>(a: A) => `hello!`

// call examples
const c0 = func(undefined) // error
const c1 = func(null) // error
const c2 = func(() => undefined) // error
const c3 = func(10) // error
const c4 = func(`hi`) // error
const c5 = func({}) // error
const c6 = func(foo) // error <-- Restricted now
const c7 = func(foo_SubType) // ok  <-- Still allowed
const c8 = func(foo_DiffSubType) // error <-- NO MORE ALLOWED !
```

*See in [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#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-y1QbhavrZLpaBUNwJBIBBIr88b6qYfemraq+YDvp+36RkUBp-rOKJmtioBWuKz52mBX5Xk6MF3iiHqoR+6GQX6WEAcG+Khnh4FXlGxFQSi8YUQR5YpjR96ZiB9plsmRQ5ixBZ9Bs3ClnY8IALQiaAWDEgIADuUpXhWvE1tsAlCaJ4mSSSsmyE2qBTnpyCoPcTxOjUvZEF8hCkD8WAUCQjxkECun6ZOxQ+iaTrzouy6ruuAlblomIIXuUmHhcJ5KIu55shykFqB5t4wk6D6ishtrsWhEHls88X-kUSVAUoDGZVxBo5e5cE7ohj6pS+b74cVSpOmVapJbh6X1VefrNYlpHke1lGQVG3V5XRCb9YxXEpsNSVsXV4GgGpPjlBIkRFMusigAoMlXjm018SsKkgfKwliegrCRLSNKaXJkEVntSnrMWDYgRlC2ne8oBmRZWAADI-UQADq9mgKSQA)*

---

### CONCLUSION

The function below:

```js
const func = <A extends Foo>(a: A = foo_SubType) => `hello!` //error!
```

Yields this error message:

```
Type 'SubType' is not assignable to type 'A'.
  'SubType' is assignable to the constraint of type 'A', but 'A'
could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 
'Foo'.ts(2322)
```

Because Typescript infers `A` from the function call, but there's no restriction in the language limiting you to call the function with different subtypes of 'Foo'. For instance, all function's call below are considered valid:

```js
const c0 = func(foo)  // ok! type 'Foo' will be infered and assigned to 'A'
const c1 = func(foo_SubType) // ok! type 'SubType' will be infered
const c2 = func(foo_DiffSubType) // ok! type 'DiffSubType' will be infered
```

Therefore assigning a concrete type to a generic `Type Parameter` is incorrect because in TS the `Type Parameter` can *always* be instantiated to some arbitrary different subtype.

*Solution:*

Never assign a concrete type to a generic type parameter, consider it as `read-only`! Instead, do this:

```js
const func = <A extends Foo>(a: A) => `hello!` //ok!
```

See in [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKTnILxIN5QE4QIYAmcAdgDYhQAMAXFAOSV0C+AUKJFAMoCuARgCrhoKdFCy5CJclVoM6AGhz4iZCnll5mbIVAAiASwBmhngJ2jxyqRRr1GiiSum9ZvLSwDGJAM7AohhFoUYOR4RBCkdCxbOVYvYl9-BAB9U0FIIOQ0nRExGTsFKHV6TSg4nz8AuGSDY2yMvSMTPnToKPy5RRd6NzKWTwr-bmIPKHQAHgBBKAgAD2AIYgJvWAQAPgAKYun0KtSWoQBKMbWoAAMACwhSUjgAQjOoAHoniGxsOGw7-vjEj0oxkMRhsqsdnk8oHAANZ3KDsaB0MJ0KAAd30NygvGgeG83n0AHNiBACHDEHRJnQBgk-B4AIyAwzDDwglL1CDHF6QmFwnR0NnItEYrFFXEEokk4BkilUv4AJgZTJZ1VqzTMkA5EOhsPh9BV-NR6NImOxosJxNJ9GlMsqTPlE2mcwWSxWYU222OqFOl2utwe4K1QA)

Comment: Is "<A extends Foo>(a: A) => `hello!`" not equivalent to "(a: Foo) => `hello!`"?

Comment: @TrevorKarjanis they are little different for example: `<A extends Foo>(a: A = foo) => 'hello!'` produces a compile error while `(a: Foo = foo) => 'hello'` [is valid code. See here.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFLUCGAuKAJgBpNsAjAgcgAsBLK0gX3XQGM4A7AZ2CgDMEBeIhSpcBElEpRaDKC3ZdeAgK6c2yKAB4AglAgAPYBE4ATbrAQA+ABT4o+lILgBKZNagADGhAA2fnAAhF5KPHz86myEWvbCCFou7kiePv6BIaxAA)

Comment: Great explanation here :) I'd like to clarify a few points: 1. In 'WHAT IS A different subtype', you say that `Foo` is a type. `SubFoo` and `DiffSubType` are its subtypes. But `DiffSubType` is considered as a different subtype. Why? `SubFoo` and `DiffSubType` both implement same prop1 and both add one additional prop, shouldn't they be both be just subtypes of `Foo`? 2. In 'CONCLUSION', in the first code sample, why `foo_SubType` can't be assigned to `A` constraint? `foo_SubType`, (let's say) has additional props and prop1 as same as `foo_Type` type, so it should be ok to assign it, right?

Comment: As a follow up, I finally got the point of my 2nd question.Because in `const func = <A extends Foo>(a: A = foo_SubType) => 'hello!'`, `func` can be called with a different subtype like:`func<DiffSubType>()`, so the assignment `a: A = foo_SubType` isn't possible, because now `A` now is set to `DiffSubType` which is not compatible type for `foo_SubType`, so typescript complains. And yeah, as you said, there're could be endless amount of subtypes of a particular type. So it's impossible to know if `foo_SubType` can be assigned to `DiffSubType` in my sample above.Can you help me with 1st question?

Comment: @Max Thank you. you asked: `Why? SubFoo and DiffSubType both implement same prop1 and both add one additional prop, shouldn't they be both be just subtypes of Foo?` They're just subtypes of Foo, you're not wrong. The question is: Given they ARE subtypes, are they equal or different subtype? Answer: Different because they add different properties/methods in relation to each other.
[See this example here](http://shorturl.at/bswBP) (maybe you are more familiar with interface keyword).

Comment: Some hints: Regarding "understand the error", the message will always print `{}`, not `unknown`. `{}` is the generic default type of `Styles` here, that is applied, because no generic argument has been set in `StylesObject` for `Styles`. Also `{}` is not an empty type, but rather one of the *top types in TS*. Meaning, you can assign almost anything to `{}`. It roughly is `unkown` minus `null` and `undefined`.

Comment: @ford04 thank you. I made the updates to the answer to reflect your comments.

Comment: Excellent explanation. However, I encountered [one situation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEWIDwAqcoMwKAJgM5wDecAhgFxyUxSYoDmA3HAEbNW7LnAC+APgAUASloAoOHBgBPMMDgBBOAF44ABUxoA1oQA0cAKIg0AGyTlgeI8GUQEcAuYDk9L+PEKSqrqAEI6tAyCbBycYoEqanAAwuFaAGRwIXKBaDiscCDMRLqoDggcwOQAhAzUSYFQwDBIULggcqJAA) that produces the error yet still confuses me. In the linked example, type `C` should be equivalent to the type paramter `T`. Is this simply a limitation of mapped types (which `Pick` uses internally)?

Comment: @MrWolfZ In expression `const f = <T extends X>(a: T) => //...`, the term `extends` express a requirement that `T` MUST obey any of following two requeriments: or (1) `T` is equal to `X`, or; (2) `T` is equal to _any arbitrary sub-type of `X`_. People _erroneusly_ assume that the term `extends` only express (1) and not express (2). But because (2) is also possible, TS inhibits you to assign a particular instance of type `X` to type `T` and expect you to choose a different approuch if you want to remain type-safe. (So in your case it's not a limitation on Pick, it's a limitation on `T` itself).

Comment: This works for me `const func = <A extends Foo>(a: A = foo_SubType as Foo)`

Comment: @transang [still not working for me](http://shorturl.at/dtxGH), can you send an working example?

Comment: @FlavioVilante there was a mistake in my last comment. The working one should be `const func = <A extends Foo>(a: A = foo_SubType as A)`. Check [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMAjDAvDAPAQRgUwA8p8wATCGaAJwEswBzAPgAoBDALhj0wHI4QIXjDaUcASgxMYAAwAW+ADaKQAQhkwA9JpgB3ENQDWqgFDbQkWImRpMuAsVIUqUOo1aduGGP0G9J6NLySirqWjoAotTUBqpAA). Hope this help!

Comment: the way typescript interprets this syntax is just nonsense, when someone writes ` <A extends string>(a: A = 'foo')` he (most likely) means that `a` should have a default value of `"foo"` which of type string and this is perfectly fine

Comment: @EliavLouski IMHO, in the first place your question should be: why to use generics given you do not need it? You can solve your proposed problem of defaulting a  string variable just doing this: `const f = (a: string = 'foo') => { //implementation };`.

Comment: Excellent explanation. You mentioned the 2 causes for this. But how about in this example (lines 52 and 63 of Picker.tsx): https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-elion-1fx0s?file=/src/Picker.tsx Neither seem to fall under the 2 possible causes or am I missing something?

Comment: very good answer, here is another practice https://github.com/semlinker/awesome-typescript/issues/19

Comment: The error is gone if to add type assertion to a param: `const func1 = <A extends string>(a: A = 'foo' as A) => 'hello!'`

Comment: @Malkaviano can you edit the answer, with your suggestions? I think it is the best way to add your contribution.

Comment: @FlavioVilante the poster error and my error are different, sorry for inconvenience I deleted the comment. my error is about T may be instantiated with another derived class something, which I fixed another way. Regards.

Comment: So how _do_ you restrict a generic to only a specific subtype or union of types? This has to be the most confusing part of TypeScript, where you want a generic to be just one of, say, 2 types, and only allow those types and not subtypes.

Answer (score 78):

That error is warning you, that your Generic Type `P` can't be assigned to `{}`, since the Generic Type `P` can be a more defined, or restricted, to a particular type that can conflict with the default value.

That means that the value `{}` can't satisfy all the possible Types that can be used by the Generic Type `P`.

Let's create another example with only booleans that should be easier to understand:

```
interface OnlyBoolIdentityInterface<T extends boolean> {
  (arg: T): T;
}

function onlyBoolGeneric<T extends boolean>(arg: T = false): T {
  return arg;
}
```

if you define a Type that is more specific than a boolean for example:

```
type TrueType = true;
```

and if you specialised the function `OnlyBoolIdentityInterface` to only support true values like this:

```
const onlyTrueIdentity: OnlyBoolIdentityInterface<TrueType> = onlyBoolGeneric;
```

even if TrueType respects the constraint set by `T extends boolean` the default value `arg: T = false` is not a `TrueType`.

This situation is what the error is trying to convey to you.

So how can you fix this type of errors?

1. Or you remove the default value
2. Or T needs to extend the specialised type of the default param that on my example is false
3. Or T can interfere directly with params that receive default params

For more context about this error message see the issue that suggested this error message https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29049.

Comment: I don't understand either of the answers. I *think* I get the mechanics that makes it impossible, but I don't get *why* this would be an intended warning. Using `fn` from your answer, both `fn(true)` and `fn(false)` are correct, right? Isn't the `= false` part in the function definition giving it a default value, so `fn()` would be equivalent to `fn(false)`? Why would `obj` possibly being `true` affect my intention that the default parameter shall be `false`?

Comment: @ShioT when you create a Generic function you allow someone using the function to make a new version of it more specialised. So if a make a newer version that only accepts true values your default value will break that possible specialised version [maybe this other example code that I created will help](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIHt0BsCSATCcYMATwDEQAeAFQD5kBvAWAChl3kAKOKAcwC5k1AJSDqAblYBfVqxgBXEAjDB0IZMAJFSGbDWQQAHpBB4AzsgBGmLBDgha3PmOQBeZPCxmIooY1YcyFAQYPJQ6jy8kiwyLKykAA4o1FDyENQkSW7IYKkQ0awIamZgyADyIFgkKWn4hCqkFIK6uFoN5FQ16ZkQ9O6a9cQkLQUsQA)

Comment: @Fetz This makes sense now.

Comment: Reading thread for the third time, what I figured so far: To fix this you probably need to simplify code or remove default params. Agree this is probably better intended as an error message.

Comment: Yes you are correct Thomazella. Because the Generic type can potentially conflict with the default params the best option is most likely not to use the default param since the obj is both affected by T and the default param.

Comment: I'm not able to understand solutions 2 and 3. Can you please update your answer to include examples for the solutions to 2 and 3?

Comment: Stuff like this makes me wish I never got started with TypeScript. I rather become a farmer than deal with this convoluted nonsense!

Answer (score 3):

A bit shorter explanation.

Example that throws error:

```
type ObjectWithPropType<T> = {prop: T};

// Mind return type - T
const createCustomObject = <T extends ObjectWithPropType<any>>(prop: any): T => ({ prop });

type CustomObj = ObjectWithProp<string> & { id: string };

const customObj = createCustomObj<CustomObj>('value'); // Invalid
// function will only ever return {prop: T} type.
```

The problem here is that the return object will only ever match the attribute `prop` and not any other attribute. Extending the `ObjectWithPropType` gives a false sense of type constraint. This example is all in all a wrong approach it was used just for illustration to show actual conflict in object attributes.

How to constrain subtype in create function:

```
type StringPropObject = ObjectWithPropType<string>

const createCustomObject = <T>(prop: T extends ObjectWithPropType<infer U> ? U : T): ObjectWithPropType<T> => ({ prop });

const stringObj = createCustomObject<StringPropObject>('test');
```

In this case, the function requires the argument to be a string. The object only has `prop` attribute and function do return required shape.

Answer (score 2):

Complementing to @flavio-vilante's great answer.

If you still want to do *(the argument `a` can be omitted and if it's omitted, fallback to `foo_SubType`)*

```js
const func = <A extends Foo>(a: A = foo_SubType) => `hello!` //error!
```

can try:

```js
const func = <A extends Foo>(a?: A) => {
    const aa = a === undefined ? foo_SubType : a;
    return `hello!`;
}
```

Or, maybe you don't really want generic type but just type `Foo` directly instead.

```js
const func = (a: Foo = foo_SubType) => `hello!`
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I wanted todo select component with generic type of enum (T extends enum) which end up as

```js
export function BasicSelector<T extends string>(props: IProps<T>) {
```

and for event hanlder I got this error "Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'.". So eventually I enforced the type

```js
          onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value as T)}
```