# Extending a union type exactly

Tags: typescript

Suppose the following sample code:

```
type Action = "GET" | "POST" | "PUT";
type Handler<A extends Action> = (action: A) => void;

const handlers: Partial<Record<Action, Handler<Action>>> = { };

function register<A extends Action>(action: A, handler: Handler<A>) {
    /*
    Error:
    Type 'Handler<A>' is not assignable to type 'Partial<Record<Action, Handler<Action>>>[A]'.
        Type 'Handler<A>' is not assignable to type 'Handler<Action>'.
            Type 'Action' is not assignable to type 'A'.
            'Action' is assignable to the constraint of type 'A', but 'A' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Action'.
                Type '"GET"' is not assignable to type 'A'.
                '"GET"' is assignable to the constraint of type 'A', but 'A' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Action'.
     */
    handlers[action] = handler;
}
```

To my understanding, this error above occurs because `A` allows for types *larger* than `Action` (e.g. it could be `Action | "DELETE"`), but my `handlers` record only allows for `exactly` the `Action` union type. There are ways I can sort of work around this:

- Cast down `handler` internally. This quiets down the compiler without actually solving the problem, as the user can still pass a larger type into `register`. Plus, casts are never ideal :)
- Make the function concrete, `register(action: Action, handler: Handler<Action>)`. This now means that `action` and `handler` don't have to agree in their types, which can lead to runtime errors.

As neither of these workarounds fully solve the issue, is there a way for me to enforce that `action` and `handler` both use the same `A`, while also not allowing for `A` to be any larger than `Action`?

---

Edit:

I've actually found an even smaller minimum repro that gives the same error:

```
function foobar<T extends "foo" | "bar">(func: (arg: T) => void): (arg: "foo" | "bar") => void {
    return func;
}
```

where the return statement gives the same error as above. This reveals the actual issue: `T` can actually be *smaller* than the union, so you might end up passing in a function that can handle less cases than what's expected.

Comment: A good solution won't exist unless [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14520) or [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808) is implemented so just cast it

Comment: `A extends Action` doesn't allow `A` to be anything "larger" than `Action`.  It cannot be `Action | "DELETE".  `A extends B` means that `A` is a *subtype* of `B`, or that if you have a value of type `A` it must also be of type `B`.  A value of type `Action | "DELETE"` is not required to be a value of type `Action`, since it might be `"DELETE"`.

Comment: You probably want `handlers` to be defined as a mapped type that correlates the key to the value: `const handlers: {[K in Action]?: Handler<K>} = {};`

Comment: But the issue will remain that the compiler can't see that `handlers[action]` and `handler` are compatible, for the reasons @Austaras mentioned.  There's not great support for [correlated](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) types in TypeScript and this has only gotten worse since TS3.5 has gotten more [strict](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769) with indexed access.

Comment: Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59363875/8233039) it tries to completely interpret what this kind of message want to mean. Let me know if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good solution won't exist unless [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14520) or [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808) is implemented so just cast it.

`A extends Action` doesn't allow `A` to be anything "larger" than `Action`. It cannot be `Action | "DELETE"`. `A extends B` means that `A` is a subtype of `B`, or that if you have a value of type `A` it must also be of type `B`. A value of type `Action | "DELETE"` is not required to be a value of type `Action`, since it might be `"DELETE"`.

You probably want `handlers` to be defined as a mapped type that correlates the key to the value: `const handlers: {[K in Action]?: Handler<K>} = {};`

But the issue will remain that the compiler can't see that `handlers[action]` and `handler` are compatible, for the reasons mentioned in the first sentence above. There's not great support for [correlated](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) types in TypeScript and this has only gotten worse since TS3.5 has gotten more [strict](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769) with indexed access.

Comment: This is a copy-and-paste of upvoted comments, which were posted under the question -- which I repost here as an answer, in case those comments are deleted.

Answer (score 1):

When you `extend` a type in TypeScript you are extending the **constraints** on the type (which means you are **reducing** the range of values the type can contain).

If you want to be able to "extend" the range of values (in the way you're thinking about it), you need to start with a wide scope for your initial type definition so you can narrow that initial broad scope to the subset of values you want. Try this:

```
type BroadAction = "GET" | "POST" | "PUT" | string;
function foo<T extends BroadAction>() {
  // do something
}
foo<"GET" | "POST" | "PUT" | "INFO" | "DELETE">();
```

The above code lets you "extend" the allowed list of actions in the way you're thinking about, by framing it in the context of extending the constraints on the type from allowing all strings to just allowing some strings.

The downside of the nature of `extend` in TypeScript is that the following lines are also valid.

```
type BroadAction = "GET" | "POST" | "PUT" | string;
function foo<T extend BroadAction>() {
  // do something
}
foo<"GET">();

type Action = "GET" | "POST" | "PUT";
function bar<T extends Action>() {
  // do something
}
bar<"GET">();
```