# 'CustomEnum.Case' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'CustomEnum'

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am defining an interface where one of the type of the property depends on a generic param P bound to an enum. I am using the following approach:

```
export enum Scopes {
  Fruit = 'fruit',
  Vegetables = 'vegetables',
}

export enum FruitItemTypes {
  Strawberry = 'strawberry',
  Rasberry = 'rasberry'
}

export enum VegetableItemTypes {
  Potatoes = 'potatoes',
  Carrots = 'currency',
}


export type ItemTypes = FruitItemTypes | VegetableItemTypes

interface ItemTypeForScope {
  [Scopes.Fruit]: FruitItemTypes;
  [Scopes.Vegetables]: VegetableItemTypes;
}

export interface Item {
  id: string;
  type: ItemTypes;
}
export interface ScopedItem<T extends Scopes> extends Item {
  type: ItemTypeForScope[T];
}
export interface ScopedData<T extends Scopes> {
  items: ScopedItem<T>[];
}

export type Data = { [scope in Scopes]: ScopedData<scope> };
```

I also want to use `ScopedItem<T>` as the return type of the following function:

```
const getItemType = <T extends Scopes>(data: Data, scope: T): ScopedItem<T>[] => {
    return data[scope].items 
}
```

However I am getting the following error, but according to me the generic param T will eventually be one of the enum case.

```
Type 'ScopedItem<Scopes.Fruit>[] | ScopedItem<Scopes.Vegetables>[]' is not assignable to type 'ScopedItem<T>[]'.
  Type 'ScopedItem<Scopes.Fruit>[]' is not assignable to type 'ScopedItem<T>[]'.
    Type 'ScopedItem<Scopes.Fruit>' is not assignable to type 'ScopedItem<T>'.
      Type 'Scopes.Fruit' is not assignable to type 'T'.
        'Scopes.Fruit' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Scopes'.
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwMoGMJmAZzgG8AoOOAMSmQEt4BeOAcgDNq6mAaMuANWADmwGAEMARgBsCcRkwBug4eKn4uJAL4kSoSLAQp0VWjACSMYKgAqATzyFS5DDCgiA7mOBQo1mc3zO3Dy9rNXIAJRF8IO9fJhcoz28mDS0daHgkND5FUUlgMwsbO2IeAAUIURgIaVlISurVbnIAYREvCsJZLDaoDrVNbXB0uBhbYDgCqzHOynZTcynigB9soVypSaKCLRpEcygWESxxzbGKaGxccYc4AG1LuwA6IzoAXQAuWeNTuwBuHnuOCe-DWygIH1WSjyPwI-wGaT0u32h2OEwWJXINAAJp9-FBdgJ-uRRnhPjD8HDBrp4EjPCjxg9gFjJgAeSwIEDmRBYwiM-AAPg5XJ5aIsGJGYzJCy25ygjNullelIRNL2dKODKBTIAIiJRGyhUgRXzBTc6BZ8J9GcyFmz+bclSkqcMSeNdaJfEQ7vgtXBdpgtfgIdb3SIWT6roL1P8SDhEP44GsYb4DaBhbzA-yABRYvUiT6hzhwCOkuCWACUVq1NosdodMlNPHIUGEyCgiDgudEtxLwFej3NqHwTq0o5IQA)

Comment: About your playground link... those are not unions and intersections.  You are using  [logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_()) which are very different.  `x || y` and `x && y` will always evaluate to one of `x` or `y` depending on the truthiness/falsiness of `x`.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer and the issue reference, I believe `Data[T]["items"]` is the same as the inferred type by the compiler. Type assertion seems like a good solution in that case. Regarding logical operators, it was a long day but thanks for the feedback regarding the irrelevance of it in this example :)

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59363875/8233039) is very detailed about this error message. Take a look on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem here is the same one described in [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29528)... you want the compiler to evaluate `{[K in Scopes]: ScopedData<K>}[P]` to something like `ScopedData[P]`, where `P` is a generic type parameter that extends `K`.  But the compiler doesn't do this sort of higher-order reasoning where a generic function of a concrete type is simiplified *before* the generic type is resolved; there has been a [suggestion](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25879) to make this happen in some cases, but it's not there as of TS3.5.

So, workarounds... it *is* possible for the compiler to verify the following:

```
const getItemType = <T extends Scopes>(
  data: Data,
  scope: T
): Data[T]["items"] => {
  return data[scope].items;
};
```

Instead of returning the type of `data[scope].items` as `ScopedItem<T>[]`, return it as `Data[T]["items"]`.  Those will turn out to be the same thing, and when you actually *call* `getItemType()` on a concrete-typed `scope` parameter, it will end up as the same concrete type.

---

Or you can just admit that your reasoning skills are superior to those of the compiler, and use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to let the compiler know who's the boss:

```
const getItemTypeAssertion = <T extends Scopes>(
  data: Data,
  scope: T
): ScopedItem<T>[] => {
  return (data[scope] as ScopedData<T>).items; // I am smarter than the compiler 
};
```

---

Hopefully one of those will work for you.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwMoGMJmAZzgG8AoOOAMSmQEt4BeOAIgDNq6mAaMuANWADmwGAEMARgBsCcRkwBug4eKn4mJAL4kSoSLAQp0VWjACSMYKgAqATzyFS5DDCgiA7mOBQo1mc3zO3Dy9rLh4AJRF8IO9fJhcoz281TW1waHgkND5FUUlgMwsbO2IeAAUIURgIaVlISurVbnIAYREvCsJZLDaoDuStHXS4GFtgOAKrUc7KdlNzSeKAH2yhXKkJooIAbi0aRHMoFhEsMY3RimhsXDHQc0QAE0Iw4Bwoe4AeK7tOcfnN-AAfCVyABtL4EAB0RjoAF0AFwzYxnOw7UHg-AQ-irZQEeErJR5ZHbDQDNJ6PYHI4nX4WYFwGj3BH+KB7ASo4ajBFE-A7TSDcn7TxUsbg+4Td6WBAgO6PTA4OxA25IWUTOkjPBcv7nS7y4Agyww3mpXTwClC44i3X3AAiIlEEqlMsI6KBDnp83wCNF4ssAJBhpJxqG6rGttEviIcBB+F19MQcuu+DxorDIneMeuQPUOxIOEQ-jgqyJvgdSoezt1gIAFDx7naRAjU004BmNXBLCQAJSN+v6mEgph0CyqGEyV08KDCZBQeN10TR3UwiFD1A8jQ5vMFotavAAQXw+E8MBoEHjjFL0uVFcTAJr5DnDbgTZ4reACI73YTeDF8wlftH9DjuQk4wNO8ZVg+C7XKOkRfsANr1n+nbLh6vI5loWhSPAr6+OiUKzDsm7wOYBaMNuhSjFWRDqHAsEiIg1g-Hh0IwJ2OYAPTsXArgABY+G0YzWBAyBwMg+Csi2PHpAAtFgNBQFgxhwBIEACDQ3QSHA1wuFUUCEDxnjAAA-CQOGMMxsxwAAZFZcEYliBIqIRp4FiRMAAEy+ORCzAFRNF0QxPyvmxWhmXZ+FKYsyx4Q5azEkRwwEDAADMXnCESfm0YQ9GMS2saweiIVAA)