# How to provide default value for union type parameter without getting "could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint"

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

As a follow-up to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58533379/how-to-get-function-to-narrow-return-value-type-to-specific-subtype-instead-of-r/58533650#58533650)...

Is there a way to provide a default value for `valueProp` in the following example?

```
type ValueType = 'value' | 'defaultValue'

type Props<T extends ValueType> =
  Record<T, string> 
  & { other: string }

function props<T extends ValueType>(valueProp: T): Props<T> {
  return {
    [valueProp]: 'value',
    other: 'other',
  } as Props<T>
}

let { defaultValue, other } = props('defaultValue') // ok
let { value } = props('value') // ok
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QCrmgXigcgG6Io5QA+uAJhAGZxILDzIQ4BQLokUACgE4D2YAM4AeVFAgAPYBAB25QbEJoMAPiiYWUKACUIAYz49yogDRRBwHgEsZAczWaoAMigBvKH2AALCDwBc5pY2tlAAvmxUSDJ6wFZ8MlBg-EKi4lKy8opM6JAqABQETLwCAagAlAHFKahqro48EMBIPAl1WloA2oUoVQC6AfhKOCaOWp4+-rjjvsOOoVBwClUiNSzhLAD0G1CoEBaCLAiNblCUNHQMSmbTPGHqicmCeThntPSMRGVQWx4A1ofHdzdaDzbBJARPQZMHBfH58f4sSLRWLxNKQGKCAAi1DelyYeVcrwuHwg128vlClUewheOOJQxUXzaUAMMkEfCOADoEHxbM8ie8lH5hqc6YKmGU1ixJOjgFixXiUHlwUJ+QqSTDYdt4dKJLL5edxUqVZDgZrvttfPweGZFmj9NJyEA)

---

When I try this:

```
function props<T extends ValueType>(valueProp: T = 'value'): Props<T> {
  return {
    [valueProp]: 'value',
    other: 'other',
  } as Props<T>
}
```

, I get this error:

```
Type '"value"' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  '"value"' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'ValueType'.
```

I understand this error ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505560/could-be-instantiated-with-a-different-subtype-of-constraint-object/56701587#56701587), [2](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29049), [3](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29397#issuecomment-453864746), [4](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33436#issuecomment-531738967)) in general, but still don't always know the best way to *resolve* this error.

Is there an easy way to do what I'm trying to do?

It just seems like there ought be an easy way to provide a default value, but maybe default values just don't mix so well with generic type constraints?

### Default type for the generic type?

I tried this:

```
function props<T extends ValueType = 'value'>(valueProp: T = 'value'): Props<T> {
  return {
    [valueProp]: 'value',
    other: 'other',
  } as Props<T>
}
```

but of course got the same error, because T could still be `defaultValue` if a specific `T` is provided:

```
props<'defaultValue'>()
```

### Type assertions?

I thought of doing this, which compiles, but still doesn't prevent `valueProp` from disagreeing with T:

```
function props<T extends ValueType>(valueProp: T = 'value' as T): Props<T> {
  return {
    [valueProp]: 'value',
    other: 'other',
  } as Props<T>
}

console.log(props<'defaultValue'>())
// => {value: "value", other: "other"}
```

### Something more complicated?

I'm still hoping there's a simple solution, but if not, maybe something more complicated would work?

Maybe using a mapping table that maps from a *type* to the default *value* for that type?

For inspiration, maybe something kind of like:

- ['CustomEnum.Case' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'CustomEnum'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57363278/customenum-case-is-assignable-to-the-constraint-of-type-t-but-t-could-be/57366095#57366095)
  or
- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29528#issuecomment-456804257
  ?

Comment: Use the overload approach i first suggested in my answer . You can add an overload without the extra parameter and the implementation signature (the last one) can have a value for the parameter since it is not generic

Comment: Okay, I guess overloads have important uses after all! :) Thanks for pointing out the simple solution yet again.

Comment: The reason I'm trying to avoid function overloads, by the way, is that this won't be the _only_ dynamic key based on parameters — and I'm afraid if I had to enumerate every possible _combination_ of params using overloads, it could result in a combinatorial explosion. I guess I'll wait to worry about that problem until I actually run into it, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Titian Cernicova-Dragomir's comment, we can do this pretty simply using function overloads:

```
type ValueType = 'value' | 'defaultValue'

type Props<T extends ValueType> =
  Record<T, string> 
  & { other: string }

function props<T extends ValueType>(valueProp: T): Props<T>
function props(): Props<'value'>
function props(valueProp: ValueType | undefined = 'value') {
  return {
    [valueProp]: 'value',
    other: 'other',
  }
}
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QCrmgXigcgG6Io5QA+uAJhAGZxILDzIQ4BQLokUACgE4D2YAM4AeVFAgAPYBAB25QbEJoMAPiiYWUKACUIAYz49yogDRRBwHgEsZAczWaoAMigBvKH2AALCDwBc5pY2tlAAvmxUSDJ6wFZ8MlBg-EKi4lKy8opM6JAqABQETLwCAagAlAHFKagqLJHRsfGJyYJ5FdwtwvhKOLX1MXEJSQKthShVAYwoOdBkUZRUNhDk6rhjzGVujjwQwEg8Ca6OWgDa61UAugHdTDgmxx7evteePjx3juHhLAD0P1CoCAWQQsBC7NxQBa0ehTCABPAABjMr18YVWwyEeRwULoDB6mz+HgA1qDwe4cTClPCAIxo7AY1o3IgE-6+fg8MxwBSSSAxZak4AQ9bwgBMdOaIyx6xwLOJAqFVKgeAAzOKGW0oIS+CSwYLydRoXimPCACxqloawlswyc7kSXnScgRKIDJo8-TAQQAEQNuNheVcFKNKGRTx4oUqnWxvsptxUmyOWgMMkEfDBADoEHxbFig7C-HdITHgxAyixwu6Yt7i-71dGaH78bLtSxK56fQ3Yyg8nXpWVZdaOVAuWkHcsgA)

---

Or if we want to move `valueProp` from positional parameters into pseudo named parameters (using object destructuring):

```
type PropsOptions<VT extends ValueType | undefined> = {
  valueProp?: VT
}

function props<VT extends ValueType>({valueProp}: PropsOptions<VT>): Props<VT>
function props(): Props<'value'>
function props({ valueProp = 'value' }: PropsOptions<ValueType | undefined> = {}) {
  return {
    [valueProp]: 'value',
    other: 'other',
  }
}
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QCrmgXigcgG6Io5QA+uAJhAGZxILDzIQ4BQLokUACgE4D2YAM4B5MMACWfAHaCAPDFRQIAD2AQp5QbEJoMpKEg3VxUiOQB8UbAG8WUKASa8BAfgBcsVCwC+bDtGcheUUVNQ0tRhR0SEtMOygAJQgAYz4ecmCAGihBYB4TAHNLeIAyKGsoPmAACwgeD1z8qQKoXxYqQ2SJaSgwfiCFJVV1TW0maIhzAAprRxRA7w9AkTFJGWDzAEol-rkFc3bO7qle3ant7l3ZfB0cA46pLrXTgUEZhx1Aq1w55lad16iY57HQTfSGShUExmWLlbybcrxHgQYBIHgnWz2ewAbV+gQAuh4bkwcJl4vYqrV6rhKXVSfFfG0APRMqCoCC5QQsBAo8pQSG0eiRCAePAABmytJ4rW+fVe7zx-SJAroDFurQRLMqAGtubyKiqhTpRQBGGXYOVCBWfJU-dXwqBaur8HjZOBaFSQLpmPXAPm-UUAJnNLytFUVAiJv2IDq1fF1PL94eNDgAzCHLW9Naz476+Ya1UxRQAWDNnbNKHgut0e5RetTkNgPJ49T0pYCCAAi1EFhZQMwLwslNTqi0ur2ug9uW0R9lSMj4PIAdAg+AUpjgp0XSfye6rhZsfCw210u3ujUwppnrU5bZvz32-vCK7mTx3uzR9zor2diURNhWzppDWQz1mYQA)