# Why does Typescript say my type is "assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint"?

Tags: typescript

Consider the following Typescript code:

```
class OrderFixture {
  orderId: string;

  constructor() {
    this.orderId = "foo";
  }
}

class DecisionFixture {
  decisionId: string;

  constructor() {
    this.decisionId = "bar";
  }
}

class FixtureStore {
  order = () => new OrderFixture();
  decision = () => new DecisionFixture();
}

const fixtureStore = new FixtureStore();

export function getFixture<
  K extends keyof FixtureStore,
  T extends ReturnType<FixtureStore[K]>
>(entityName: K): T {
  return fixtureStore[entityName](); // ERROR: Type 'OrderFixture' is not assignable to type 'T'.
}
```

It yields the following type error:

```
Type 'OrderFixture | DecisionFixture' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'OrderFixture | DecisionFixture' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'OrderFixture | DecisionFixture'.
    Type 'OrderFixture' is not assignable to type 'T'.
      'OrderFixture' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'OrderFixture | DecisionFixture'.ts(2322)
```

Here is a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDyBOATApvAYgSwB4BcCu8y0A3gFDTQD2SqAkogFzQQ7wYB2A5gNynnTBK7FvDzAc1ABQBKEvwo4AFhggA6ainj1oAXmgAiAGaVK%203hQC%20pK6VCQYAEWTAVGIZlwEiZCihcQ3dnomEQ4ePgpBYVYxCXgZOQoFZTU-VyFtPX0AIzB4M34rGzsoaA98QgBlOO9%20DVRdaASdAD5odmQAdzgadGwK5BlzaDSAoUbmto7up39A8q8h6z4olmhDfq9q6iI9abLNqpql0mQsAAdqHHW8dnFA6E5kHAXCAB5%20AGloM5xkdkQMAA1sgAJ6UQwHTxHHYAGn4ABUfrh-oDoAAlZ4EdgI0HnZBvV7IbaEADanwAui1SC1JP8cBgcKCAHJgAC2yCYn2kTCRPmghAq7HWh2JNVJ9MZLPZyApQ2gAHoFdBcfjoAByBCaInq6AqdqUa72DCcdhgbIgIgSaBMtXqhHq1TWIA).

There seems to be a [fairly canonical answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59363875/5388264) to the question raised by this type of error but I am unable to see any relevant similarity between the two causes laid out there and my code.

If I force cast the return value to `T` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57366095/5388264) I get the right types when invoking `getFixture`. Why doesn't Typescript infer these types for me?

Comment: No expect on TS, but I would have expected `function getFixture(entityName:keyof FixtureStore){ return fixtureStore[entityName](); }` to also be able to infer the type of either OrderFixture or DecisionFixture as there is enough info for the compiler to work it out.

Comment: This is a great question, by the way, I've had similar issues with this before. I would say its because the inference goes as far as ```OrderFixture | DecisionFixture``` yet you would only spec one of them so you have to say which one of the two it is using the type casting...

Comment: What's even weirder if you cast as `any`, the callee still gets the correct inferred type.  mmmm

Answer (score 1):

Typescript's error message here is perfectly descriptive: your function returns something which is assignable to `OrderFixture | DecisionFixture`, but not assignable to an arbitrary subtype of it, such as e.g. `OrderFixture & HTMLCanvasElement`. If you still aren't sure, consider the following code, in which your function promises to return such a thing; it is clearly not type-safe, but it has no error, because it's only using the return type that your function claims to have.

```
let canvas = getFixture<'order', OrderFixture & HTMLCanvasElement>('order');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

Normally, for exactly this reason, you should not have a type parameter which only appears in the return position, because it allows the caller to expect a specific type without passing any argument that allows the function to know what type it is expected to return. In your case, there is no need for the type parameter `T`: just make `ReturnType<FixtureStore[K]>` the return type of your function directly.

---

That said, in this case there is something fishy going on that does seem to be Typescript's fault: even splitting up the function's logic and providing type annotations to help the compiler, Typescript still gives an error.

```
function getFixture<K extends keyof FixtureStore>(entityName: K): ReturnType<FixtureStore[K]> {
  let factory: FixtureStore[K] = fixtureStore[entityName];

  // error here
  let instance: ReturnType<typeof factory> = factory();
  
  return instance;
}}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDyBOATApvAYgSwB4BcCu8y0A3gFDTQD2SqAkogFzQQ7wYB2A5tALzQDkAM0qV+AblIBfUqEgwAIsmAYIGSu0y4CRMhRTLV6+kxZsuvAQCMw8cVJngo0TfkIBlHNR3kqNeBYAKAEpeAD5odmQAdzg-F21giT0lFTV2QJCecMiYxQM0+MJE+2B1FmhBbFdkDy8LHOcq7VqioIlSQTx2YBw06E5kHELkAB4AaWhkXGR2RBgAa2QAT0pBRq13T0JQgJnenCWAOTAAW2QmMaCmACVBgnYAFSWAB1HhluQAbTGAXXDdaAgQYVMA9ahLJjvLZfX4WSobGrQz57DAHY5nH7tCgAemxk3g8Go0AAFqhkD4gThoBwWGBuudoLdXI8XqMDq9ViCwfAluE+IJQVslsUKD5CMzqexafSJNIgA)

Logically, Typescript should never complain that the type of `factory()` might not be assignable to `ReturnType<typeof factory>`, yet here it complains of exactly that. So I think this should be looked at by someone who knows about Typescript's internals, and perhaps raised as a bug on their issue tracker.