# Generic Function Subtype Constraint Error and Confusion

Tags: typescript, generics, types, subtyping

I was playing with the idea of a simple wrapper function using TypeScript. I ended up getting something working with the following:

```js
export function logFn<T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(
  fn: T,
): (...args: Parameters<T>) => ReturnType<T>  {
  const log = (...args: Parameters<T>): ReturnType<T> => {
    console.log('log')
    return fn(...args)
  }
  return log
}
```

This works and the compiler is happy. My question is around my initial attempt which looked more like this

```js
export function logFn<T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(
  fn: T,
): T  {
  const log: T = (...args) => {
    console.log('log')
    return fn(...args)
  }
  return log
}
```

This was giving me an error at the `log` variable declaration with the error:

```
Type '(...args: any[]) => any' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  '(...args: any[]) => any' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '(...args: any[]) => any'.
```

It seems that there's some subtype relationship constraint that I can't fully wrap my head around (this error isn't doing me too many favors either). Was hoping someone with a better mental grasp on this stuff could give me a decent explanation so I can be less confused by this behavior (which I'm sure is correct).

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59363875/8233039) is very detailed about this error message. See if you can solve your problem with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "problem" is this: `T extends (...args: any[]) => any`

Its more visualisable if you see the below version:

```
export function logFn<T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(fn: T): T {
  return (a, b) => fn(a, b);
}
```

You will see the error holds

> Type '(a: any, b: any) => any' is not assignable to type 'T'.
>     '(a: any, b: any) => any' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '(...args: any[]) => any'.

Both of the below are valid as far as `T extends (...args: any[]) => any` goes

1. `logFn((a, b) => a + b)`
2. `logFn((a, b, c) => c)`

But if you refer back to the example I gave, the inner definition as:

```
return (a, b) => fn(a, b);
```

So option 2. will throw an error here, which is why typescript is warning you about it.

```
logFn<T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(fn: T): T
```

We are going to receive a type `T` and return a type `T`. `return (a, b) => fn(a, b);` is a valid return type, it does extend `(...args: any[]) => any` but how can you be sure that the value passed to `fn` (`T`) matches that signature? (i.e. it could be another incompatible subtype of `(...args: any[]) => any`)

Not sure if I explained well enough, but thats my understanding

The reason your workaround is fine is because by adding `(...args: Parameters<T>) => ReturnType<T>` you are telling the compiler the parameters & return types must match those of the passed function, as opposed to `T` which could be any other function definition