# Function could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint

Tags: typescript

TypeScript refuses to compile the `debounce` function because something wrong with type of the wrapping function:

```
export function debounce<F extends ((...args: any[]) => void)>(fn: F, timeout: number): F {
  let timer: NodeJS.Timeout | undefined

  // Problem here, TypeScript complains it's not the same function as F
  return ((...args: any[]) => {
    if (timer) clearTimeout(timer)
    timer = setTimeout(() => fn(...args), timeout)
  })
}
```

The error:

```
Type '(...args: any[]) => void' is not assignable to type 'F'.
  '(...args: any[]) => void' is assignable to the constraint of type 'F', but 'F' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '(...args: any[]) => void'.ts(2322)
```

How to fix that? Without forced typecasting `return ... as F` or `return ... as any`

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59363875/8233039) is very detailed about this error message. See if you can solve your problem with it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that the constraint `(...args: any[]) => void` on `F` can be satisified by a number of types that you might find surprising, and the function you're returning will not be assignable to such types.  For example:

```
debounce(() => "oopsie", 1000)().toUpperCase(); // okay at compile time, typeError at runtime
```

Here, the function type `F` returns a `string` value; this is assignable to a `void`-returning function type, as [explained in the FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-returning-non-void-assignable-to-function-returning-void).  But of course `debounce()` will not return a `string`-returning function, so the return type of `debounce()` is not the same `F` as passed in.

Also:

```
function foo() { };
foo.prop = 123; // property declaration
debounce(foo, 1000).prop.toFixed(); // okay at compile time, TypeError at runtime
```

In this case, we have a function with a [property declared on it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#properties-declarations-on-functions).  So the `F` type here will be a function type `()=>void` with an extra `prop` property.  But again, `debounce()` will not return a function with this extra `prop` property on it, so the return type of `debounce()` is again not the same `F` as passed in.

---

The fix here is to make `debounce()` only generic enough to represent what you're actually doing.  The returned function will take the same argument list as the passed-in function, so we need the argument list to be generic.  And the returned function will definitely return `void` and is not going to have extra properties on it.  So only the argument list needs a type parameter (say, `A`), and both the input and output functions will be of the type `(...args: A) => void`:

```
export function debounce<A extends any[]>(
    fn: (...args: A) => void,
    timeout: number
): (...args: A) => void {
    let timer: NodeJS.Timeout | undefined

    return ((...args: A) => {
        if (timer) clearTimeout(timer)
        timer = setTimeout(() => fn(...args), timeout)
    })
}
```

That compiles with no error.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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)

Comment: But how would you widen this to allow other return types?