# "A is assignable to the constraint of type B but B could be instanciated with a different subtype" in generic component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following component `DataListBase` :

```js
export type Page<T> = {
  total: number;
  items: T[];
};

type Filters = {
  search: string | null;
  sort: string | null;
  sortOrder: number | null;
  limit: number;
  page: number;
};

type DataListBaseProps<TData, TVariables> = {
  query: DocumentNode;
  variables: Omit<TVariables, "page">;
};

export const DataListBase = <
  TData extends Record<string, Page<TInner>>,
  TVariables extends Pick<Filters, "limit" | "page">,
  TInner = any
>({
  query,
  variables
}: DataListBaseProps<TData, TVariables>) => {
  const actualVariables: TVariables = useMemo(
    () => ({
      ...variables,
      page: 1
    }),
    [variables]
  );

  const result = useQuery<TData, TVariables>(query, {
    variables: actualVariables
  });

  // rest is not important
  return null;
}
```

On the declaration of `actualVariables`, it says :

```
Error:(22, 9) TS2322: Type 'Pick<TVariables, Exclude<keyof TVariables, "page">> & { page: number; }' is not assignable to type 'TVariables'.
  'Pick<TVariables, Exclude<keyof TVariables, "page">> & { page: number; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'TVariables', but 'TVariables' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Pick<Filters, "page" | "limit">'.
```

I fail to see how this makes sense. `Pick<TVariables, Exclude<keyof TVariables, "page">> & { page: number; }` is actually strictly the same as `TVariables`. In my understanding, it just removes the page key, and then re-adds it. How is this not exactly the same as the type we had to start with ? And how should I correct my code ?

Thank you.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56701587/4509338) help?

I.e. it seems that the type you're assigning has a potentially less defined/restricted type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your issue is probably something like this:

```
function f<T extends { limit: number, page: number }>(
  t: T,
  x: Omit<T, "page"> & { page: number; }
): T {
  return x; // error!
}
```

The compiler is unable to verify that `x` is of type `T`.  And actually `x` might *not* be of type `T`, as in the following example:

```
interface PageSeven {
  limit: number,
  page: 7; // only seven, that's it
}
const page7: PageSeven = { limit: 123, page: 7 };
const oopsPage7 = f(page7, { limit: 456, page: 100 });
console.log(oopsPage7.page); // 7 at compile time, 100 at runtime, oops
```

The compiler thinks that `oopsPage7.page` is of the [numeric literal type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#numeric-literal-types) `7` instead of the wider `number` type, but at runtime `oopsPage7.page` will be `100`.  Oops.

If you have an object type `V`, then a type `U extends V` can be a subtype of it either by adding new properties or by *narrowing the types of existing properties*.  In this latter case, you can't recover `V` by taking `Pick<U, keyof V>`; you might still have a narrower type, as with `Page7` above.

---

But you're on to something... it turns out that you can represent actually valid transformations similar to this that are perfectly type safe, but the compiler *still* won't be able to verify it:

```
function g<T extends { limit: number, page: number }>(
  t: T,
  x: Omit<T, "page"> & Pick<T, "page">
): T {
  return x; // still error!
}
g(page7, { limit: 456, page: 100 }); // error at compile time
g(page7, page7); // okay
```

Here the compiler is still complaining about `return x`; even though the type `Omit<T, "page"> & Pick<T, "page">` really seems very definitely assignable to `T`, since even narrowed `page` properties will be preserved.  This is a [known issue in TypeScript, see microsoft/TypeScript#28884](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28884).  The issue is that the compiler doesn't usually go through the effort of verifying that a non-generic object can be assignable to a type that depends on an unspecified generic type parameter.  It's possible that this will eventually be addressed, but it's not clear; even if it can be done correctly, it needs to be done efficiently enough so as not to significantly worsen compiler performance.  I wouldn't hold my breath here if I were you.

---

So, what can be done?  If you are sure that a narrowing like I'm mention with `PageSeven` won't happen, or you don't care about it, you can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) (`expr as Type`).  This is the usual recommendation for a situation in which you know that something you're doing is type safe and the compiler doesn't (with the caveat that you should triple-check the safety because you've taken on the responsibility of verifying it):

```
function f<T extends { limit: number, page: number }>(
  t: T,
  x: Omit<T, "page"> & { page: number; }
): T {
  return x as T; // no error, technically unsafe
}

function g<T extends { limit: number, page: number }>(
  t: T,
  x: Omit<T, "page"> & Pick<T, "page">
): T {
  return x as T; // no error, probably safe
}
```

On the other hand, you could annotate your functions so that they deal with `Omit<T, "page"> & {page: number}` instead of `T`:

```
function f<T extends { limit: number, page: number }>(
  t: T,
  x: Omit<T, "page"> & { page: number; }
): Omit<T, "page"> & { page: number; } {
  return x;
}
const okayPage100 = f(page7, { limit: 456, page: 100 });
console.log(okayPage100.page); // number at compile time, 100 at runtime, okay

function g<T extends { limit: number, page: number }>(
  t: T,
  x: Omit<T, "page"> & Pick<T, "page">
): Omit<T, "page"> & Pick<T, "page"> {
  return x;
}
const ret: PageSeven = g(page7, page7); // still okay
```

Either way should work.  The assertion is probably the most convenient while being possibly (slightly) unsafe, while the reannotating might spread to your whole code base while being only slightly more safe than the assertion.  It's up to you though.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAPAFUQUwB5U2AEwGdEBvRAGxgFsYoAuRMEagI0wCcAaRABwEMA5pkbM2nRAF8AfAAoAsAChEiBojRclK7IwAKMCAGt0PAERVaUU9KUBKRhlJbEHTFBAck2ANyIA9H5YHBxwHACESpJKSjBgeBzA-BCYiLpCmADKmABu+GTOFnSiLOzczgLCjADsvgGICBQAnohEOfg8UAAW-FAA5CR0kUoQCERQfOlVeulZuUgAvGSUNEWIAIwATADMPBUiiFVS3sOj43BwvERpwoeLwLJ7VTzkhWoALACsAGy76YxrAAYAVJbMdFCMwEQ4BRMAA6ChwQSyc6Xa6YKqwvag-yBQ49RAjai8GAw1Q0TA8QHA-EccCwagU+oXIjRRRKUCQWAIRCCdBYXD4YhLV7FcTcCaVJglCQyBTKVQOTTynSIADylhMiFMe2siAAZKkDMYNFqdTZFPZ1Pl5a53J5ED4cUEQuEhookY9nstLIxPj8JfsqSDaoFeK45ngCIh8YTiaT6ZglB7Jr8bti6nBDPxGqz2eBoPAkMAAIJEVocKB8nB4QgkF4rNRiUqp-ZNmVyZxqDTOFXquia7XpXUG8h7UWlXxRC0Oa0qW0eLzRkhoENMODO0IdTAQTpgAz8ChNRDgIj8YCJxRTjkF7mCUvlysYauCuve1Zt8VjqViqQd+VdpVtEYPtHzMM19UNIwBzNOwZycG03AXB0l3UVcwHXTgXV2EJWH4Vgj1Pc83TzTlC2QAAlTB+DAdCoB6TAqwFWthQbcdOBbNiOF-OUVAAntgI1E1B2EYcli-D9J1gtVBLAodpAg0c-m-CcpFnFxEPtHw3QhMZ6izRo0SDO5KOo2j6IeFMWJ9RA-Q49YgWDE5IWhOEESRTNs0MoFMXSdNAg-aNxljEkUgTSkHJpOlyR4DyczZRRry5JBBBMmi4DovBGJrIV62sj87IC2VO0VRB+Ok-shPAg19Cgyq5KkkDoLkiCauNWSRPk+C5w0rwwSnHTxltaZhFmPJFhSqi0oyzALJuFsqj8lpYEPPTsyAA)

Comment: That's an awesome response. I'll go for the assertion, thank you!