# Generic higher-order React component gives type errors

Tags: reactjs, typescript, higher-order-components

I'm trying to write a generic React component that requires props of one of two types (`IFoo` or `IBar`) and a component that accepts props of the selected type.

How come the following doesn't work?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4BYAKCuADsYkpN0k4BJAMQgjgG8q4cAB4AuOAGcYUOgHMKlAL5Ua9RszSs2AIRRQ+A4WNoBXEACNG8pdUpoItSXEzcxydDAB0HY7QzB7AMK4kLRI9AA8nNwAfHAAvHAAFGA4YOJiURAAlPGx-JSCdg4QADZIHiUQMokARAAWSCWVTjh4zhAAhDVZ8oJEMMZQtHDhACbAAG7R7eEA9ONTVAryVEWOZrquxJ7evjD+tEHg9mEwkTpQsQnJqensFzlxeQZrpeWV1fWNzdi4cBtQLo9Az9QbDMaTaIAuYLaJLFaUOgMJgsdgABVu4QAKnk4AZBCkIGkxFiANoAXV6gjgRxCpy27i8Pj8gWCJwiOKsyhsaBKKHE4jgAAlgDIGlAAPJQUaMWnss5YuBIIQMWijQXaXRwAA+7C4EFiytV6sQ2w8ctCETYGKJ4mx0Vx+LgRDVjESOXy1K9cDW8F4cEJaQANDS2Zb4Ap4nAYHVgOIPIHxFTvc6kAMhkkIYsCinvbxEx4QCgwDcibkRhbTnwPDXAwpZtEsssnV6YZCsi3rAogA)

```js
import React from 'react';

interface IFoo {
  x: string;
}

interface IBar {
  x: number;
}

const foo: React.FunctionComponent<IFoo> = (props: IFoo) => {
  console.log("hello from foo!");
  return <div>foo</div>
};

const bar: React.FunctionComponent<IBar> = (props: IBar) => {
  console.log("hello from bar!");
  return <div>bar</div>
};

interface IProps<T> { 
    props: T[];
    Component: React.FunctionComponent<T>;
}


class HigherOrderComponent<T extends IBar | IFoo> extends React.Component<IProps<T>> { 
    render() {
        const { props, Component } = this.props;
        return (<div>
            {props.map(prop => <Component {...prop}/>)};
        </div>)
     }
}
```

This returns the following error:

```
Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & T & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Type 'IFoo | IBar' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & T & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
    Type 'IFoo' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & T & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
      Type 'IFoo' is not assignable to type 'T'.
        'IFoo' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'IFoo | IBar'.
          Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
            Type 'IFoo | IBar' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
              Type 'IFoo' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.(2322)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quick fix is to add:

```
{props.map((prop: T & {}) => <Component {...prop}/>)};
```

I think the problem is with the spread operator and union type (if there is only one type it works fine). I know TS had problems with that before :(

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you, the next question is then how to allow for specifying component keys. <Component key={prop.x} {...prop}/> will still give an error. But that should probably be another question.

Comment: It's because you cannot assign to a generic parameter directly. This comment explains it nicely: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59363875/10468320

Comment: {props.map((prop: T & object) => <Component {...prop}/>)};

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a HOC class dynamically, in order wrap a Component and have correct typings for them

```
import React from 'react';

interface IFoo {
  x: string;
}

interface IBar {
  x: number;
}

const foo: React.FunctionComponent<IFoo> = (props: IFoo) => {
    console.log("hello from foo!");
  return <div>foo</div>
};

const bar: React.FunctionComponent<IBar> = (props: IBar) => {
    console.log("hello from bar!");
  return <div>bar</div>
};

function createHOC<P extends IFoo | IBar>(Component: React.ComponentType<P>) {
  return class HigherOrderComponent extends React.Component<P> {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.x)
        return <Component {...this.props} />
     }
  }
}

const WrapperFooComponent = createHOC(foo)

const WrapperBarComponent = createHOC(bar)
```

Hope it helps <3

Comment: How is `IProps` used here? How do I access and use `IProps.props` inside `HigherOrderComponent` ?

Comment: You don't need to have them, fixed the answer. All the props are going to be available in `this.props`, so you can access `x` property from `IFoo | IBar` as `this.props.x`

Comment: Hmm, I think I might have oversimplified my problem when writing the question. I have now updated the question to better match my problem.