# typescript, overriding method in a child class: could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'

Tags: typescript

Trying to override a method in a child class, with a generic return type, and coming up with this error. I've been reading [could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'object'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505560/could-be-instantiated-with-a-different-subtype-of-constraint-object) but I can't wrap my ahead around to my scenario. Any advise?

```
Type '{ deployments: { [deploymentId: string]: string[]; }; }' is not assignable to type 'SomeInterface'.
  '{ deployments: { [deploymentId: string]: string[]; }; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'SomeInterface', but 'SomeInterface' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'.(2322)
```

```
class SomeClass {
    testGenericMethod<T>(): T {
        throw new Error('Implement this.')
    }
}

interface SomeInterface {
  deployments: { [deploymentId: string]: Array<string> }
}

class ImplementSomeClass extends SomeClass {
    testGenericMethod<SomeInterface>(): SomeInterface {
        const deployments: { [deploymentId: string]: Array<string> } = {}
        return  { deployments }
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/)

Comment: The linked post had an answer that says this message is sometimes because of duplicate type declarations. Try `testGenericMethod(): SomeInterface {`

Answer (score 0):

You are using a generic variable `<SomeInterface>` which overrides the interface definition in the scope of your function.

Use another generic variable. For instance, if it needs still to be a `SomeInterface`:

```
class ImplementSomeCLass {
    testGenericMethod<T extends SomeInterface>(): SomeInterface {
        const deployments: { [deploymentId: string]: Array<string> } = {}
        return  { deployments }
    }
}
```

Remember that in function definition, the generic types are variables. You can assign them default values

```
testGenericMethod<T = SomeInterface>(): SomeInterface {/** **/}
```

or you can constraint them to some types:

```
testGenericMethod<T extends SomeInterface>() : SomeInterface {/** **/}
```

In the former case, you can call your function with any type:

```
const myInterface = testGenericMethod<any>();
```

In the later case, you can use any type satisfying the constraint:

```
const myInterface = testGenericMethod<SomeInterface & MyOtherInterface>();
```

Comment: Thanks. I realized I mistyped the sample code. I really want `class ImplementSomeClass extends SomeClass` (extends SomeClass). I tried your suggestion of `<T extends SomeInterface>` and it now says: `'SomeInterface' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'.`. I've updated the TypeScript Playground.