# is assignable to the constraint of type 'P', but 'P' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'TextInputProps'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

It is HOC, I have follow errors:

> Type 'Pick, "children" | Exclude> & { ...; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & P & { children?: ReactNode; }'
>
> Type 'Pick, "children" | Exclude> & { ...; }' is not assignable to type 'P'.
>
> 'Pick, "children" | Exclude> & { ...; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'P', but 'P' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'TextInputProps'.

How repair it?

```
import { View, ViewStyle, StyleProp, NativeSyntheticEvent, TextStyle, TextInputProps } from 'react-native';

type Props = {
  styleWrapper?: StyleProp<ViewStyle>;
  style?: StyleProp<TextStyle>;
  title?: string;
  value?: string;
  onFocus?: (e: NativeSyntheticEvent<any>) => void;
  onBlur?: (e: NativeSyntheticEvent<any>) => void;
  onChange?: (text: string) => void;
  onReset?: () => void;
  withReset?: boolean;
};

export const withInputWrapper = <P extends TextInputProps = TextInputProps>(
  InputComponent: React.ComponentType<P>
): React.FC<P & Props> => {
  return ({ styleWrapper, style, title, value, onFocus, onBlur, onChange, onReset, withReset = true, ...props }) => {
    const onFocusHandler = ...
    const onBlurHandler = ...

    const onChangeHandler = ...

    return (
      <View style={styleWrapper}>
        <View style={s.inputWrapper}>
          <InputComponent // <-- here
            {...props}
            onChange={onChangeHandler}
            value={value}
            style={style}
            onBlur={onBlurHandler}
            onFocus={onFocusHandler}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to quote a different stackoverflow answer explaining your problem: [could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'object'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505560/could-be-instantiated-with-a-different-subtype-of-constraint-object)

Basically TS cannot infer which subtype you are using and doesn't let you assign/assume a concrete type directly.

Here's a sandbox I created which fixes a similar issue by not using generics (it's not react-native but shouldn't matter in this case): https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-tdd-91zfq

```
type Props = {
  styleWrapper?: any;
  style?: any;
  title?: string;
  value?: string;
  onFocus?: (e: any) => void;
  onBlur?: (e: any) => void;
  onChange?: (text: string) => void;
  onReset?: () => void;
  withReset?: boolean;
} & React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>;

export const withInputWrapper = (
  InputComponent: React.ComponentType<Props>
) => ({
...
```

If you want to use generics you need to cast ...props to P: `{...props as P}` inside return.

Answer (score 9):

This is one of those cases when you have reached the limit of what TS can reason about generic type parameters with conditional and mapped types. While `props` might seem obviously `P`, this is not obvious to the compiler. The compiler will use `Omit` to type `props` which uses mapped and conditional types to remove some keys from a given type. So props will be typed as `Omit<P & Props, keyof Props>`. This might seem obviously `P`, but TS can't follow conditional types as long as they still have unresolved type parameters. This means, as far as TS is concerned `Omit<P & Props, keyof Props>` and `P` are different types.

The only solution here is to use a type assertion:

```
export const withInputWrapper = <P extends TextInputProps = TextInputProps>(
  InputComponent: React.ComponentType<P>
): React.FC<P & Props> => {
  return ({ styleWrapper, style, title, value, onFocus, onBlur, onChange, onReset, withReset = true, ...props }) => {

    const onFocusHandler = () => {}
    const onBlurHandler = () => {}

      const onChangeHandler = () => {}

    return (
      <View style={styleWrapper}>
        <View>
          <InputComponent // <-- here
            {...props as P}
            onChange={onChangeHandler}
            value={value}
            style={style}
            onBlur={onBlurHandler}
            onFocus={onFocusHandler}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=41&ssc=3&pln=16&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChRJY4BvOANWCQHcAaexpgZRgE8AbJG278kABRxg2AORQxgANySceAOxgALJHLQBRRWrYAVJAA8YwgUdMwAkirABXGOIhgAznAC+cbLgJF0GABaFVkFJHwAblJSXjAkOBd3OABeGlI4ODdeAQB1KBQweKgAfgAuOAsxCQAeBmYqgD5ozOyRcsqc6tca4zMmlrg5GAEO7KhgFQBzQfkUPgckMZgJ6cGIFQAxCDQHNw6ACiQKmTlFZTVNbT0kNRqUFR5GgEpUxrh5CGAAE3WVACEFqUKkcTmFzqoNFpgLp9DB7o8Xm8Pl9fhk4BsAMLqB5TJYgmDWCrjSZTV4pd6fH5-ZBuLSHcmU1GDJjADS0+kVABGEAgAge0U80VIpko8DQG2ycFZGjsjhg+UKxVScBqojg1lu3w8fVs9icSQ8aV1coNEjcjQO6NNMExuEgKluMAqyECADo7eANk7DDx4mrGqRni7iDA3ZtMWq4AAyRLm94U9KZIgwBxQFRwA60Np5ApFJBQNg5wRDNmWD7zRZsDbbXZuasAoEN7G4ksbDkwNgy9QdlUrKtwN1DsDmryMpOZSfozISlRSms7PYACQe3wEUBVB3H1E807gs-njbTK5Ua4Lm+3u73M8l8CxOOmSBPZ43aS3yJ3MUncBTaYzVu-TI6g4LIuhSahi0VfMoE8QNAMnYDmDg+CEJtT0HSdOAAHosNVIIgjgTQiGvFDqCHN0R1cDwUA8URdxQwD71bcCmMfZ913ohjJzmBYkHAnjFk4rjQJEcDiyEriNkBNMWKPKB2ILCSGIXOtZNrZdVw4kjvyw5D4JqLD6iYPSEMMjgTOeQYhVIIUgA)