# Type predicate assignable to the constraint of type 'A', but 'A' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'

Tags: typescript

I have a type that takes an object and marks one of its properties as being unique:

```js
type UniqueString = string & { readonly UniqueString: unique symbol }

type HasUnique<A extends {}, K extends keyof A> = Omit<A, K> & Record<K, UniqueString>
```

I'm trying to write a type guard to take an A and return is HasUnique<A, K>. Here is my type guard, which gives me a type error:

```js
declare const hasUnique: <A extends {}, K extends keyof A>(a: A) => a is HasUnique<A, K>
```

> TS2677: A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type.   Type 'HasUnique<A, K>' is not assignable to type 'A'.     'HasUnique<A, K>' is assignable to the constraint of type 'A', but 'A' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'.

Is there a way to fix this, or is this one of those instances where I've hit the limitations of TS's inference with generics, as referenced in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60735375/is-assignable-to-the-constraint-of-type-p-but-p-could-be-instantiated-with) SO question?

Comment: It is not a limitation. It just how custom typeguards work. How do you call this function? There is unused `K` generic. Do you call this function with explicit two generics?

Comment: `Omit<A, K>` is a widening operation and type guards must be narrowing.  If I have `declare const obj: { a: "hello" & { readonly UniqueString: unique symbol } };` and call `hasUnique(obj)` then a `true` result would presumably be *widening* the `a` property to forget that it has a literal string type.  Why not just `A & Record<K, UniqueString>` instead of `Omit<A, K> & UniqueString`?  What's the use case? Can you show these uses in a [mre]?