# Generic function that return value of same T or different R can't accept higher order function '( i : T ) => i' as default parameter value

Tags: typescript, generics, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I would like to understand how to get where I want with generic type so this is my example :

```
function foo(value: 42 = 42 ,bar:(val: any) => any = I => I){
return bar(value)
}
```

I work with a `value` of some type `T` in my example the type is a `number` so I am using `42` I want to have a function as an argument that will change the value to a different type `R` or return a same type `T` which in this case would be the identity 'I => I' as the default parameter value.

I rewrote my function as an arrow function like this:

```
const foo = <R1>(
  value: number = 42,
  bar: <R0>(val: number) => R0 = I => I
) => {
  return bar<R1>(value);
};

const foo0 = (
  value: number = 42,
  bar: <R0>(val: number) => R0 = I => I
) => {
  return bar(value);
};

const foo1 = <R1>(
  value: number = 42,
  bar: (val: number) => R1 = I => I
) => {
  return bar(value);
};
```

`ERROR: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'RX'.
  'RX' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'number'.`

I am using `R1` and `R0` because I am not sure the difference between R one and R naught  in this example but if I remove the `I => I` default value the error message go away but I don't understand why or how to overcome it...

in the below example `fooB(42,i=>i)` and `foo0B(42,i=>i)` erored out but not `foo1B(42,i=>i)`

**How can I set the default value `I => I` without having to specify both `R | number`**

```
const fooB = <R1>(value: number = 42, bar: <R0>(val: number) => R0) => {
  return bar<R1>(value);
};

const foo0B = (value: number = 42, bar: <R0>(val: number) => R0) => {
  return bar(value);
};

const foo1B = <R1>(value: number = 42, bar: (val: number) => R1) => {
  return bar(value);
};


fooB(42,i=>i)
foo0B(42,i=>i)
foo1B(42,i=>i)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message that you get from your examples is caused by the fact that type arguments can be explicitly given when calling a function, for example:

```
fooB<number>(42, (i) => i);
```

considering `fooB`:

```
const fooB = <R1>(value: number = 42, bar: <R0>(val: number) => R0) => {
    return bar<R1>(value);
};
```

what happens here is that internally `bar` can be called with any other type besides `R1` too. If that is the case there is no guarantee that `number` (the type of `value`) is a type that's compatible with `R0`.

The problem arises when we'd do for example:

```
fooB<21>(42, (i) => i);
```

About this call we can say: `R1` is instantiated with/as `21`.

Here `42 extends number` as it's supposed to considering the type of `value`, but `number extends 21` is FALSE. In other words: *`42` and `21` are different subtypes of type `number`*. Therefore the returned `i` is not assingable to `R1` nor `R0`. A similar problem occurs with `foo0B` and `R0`.

There's already [some good coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505560/could-be-instantiated-with-a-different-subtype-of-constraint-object) on why this error message occurs.

---

### The fix

If I understand correctly, you want a function that:

- Takes an argument of type `T`
- Optionally takes a function `fn` that takes an argument of type `T` and returns a value of type `U`
- Calls `fn` with the first argument, and then returns the result (`U`) if `fn` is given, or returns `T` otherwise (the identity).

The most straightforward way to write this is like the following:

```
function foo<T, U>(value: T, fn: (val: T) => T | U = i => i): T | U {
    return fn(value);
}
```

But here both `foo` and `fn` can indeed only return the union type `T | U`, since there's only one signature to account for both the cases

- Without `fn`
- With `fn`

If you want branching of types depending on whether a callback is passed (I'm assuming this based on the default `I => I`) you can use [function overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) instead. Essentially it's like saying "I have the following 2 signatures for `foo`":

```
function foo<T>(value: T): T;
function foo<T, U>(value: T, fn: (val: T) => U): U;
function foo<T>(value: T, fn = (i: T) => i) {
    return fn(value);
}
```

The first function signature is for when no callback is passed: it takes a `T`, and will just return a `T`. In that sense `foo` is like the identity function.

The second signature takes the callback `fn`. If no type arguments are explicitly given to a call to `foo`, `U` is going to be inferred from the type of `fn`. Otherwise the type of `fn` will be validated against the given type for `U`.

Then you have the function implementation. It can account for both signatures, and does so using the identity function (default value) to match the first signature, or a given function to match the second. This *implementation signature* only explicitly specifies the types that are constant for all overloads, so only `T` is specified. The overloads will do the rest by determining the return type on a per-call basis.

Here's a complete [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcA8AVAfACgG4CGANiAKYBciGAlJRgNwBQoksCyqmANIgKq6ESFKj2BhK+YnWqIAvFj60+TFtHhIU6bJKF1RSWYhwxpchTBkBvRoluIATqSgh7GsDrLUmAX0aMA9P6IAOowUAAWcCBQiBDERABGBBAA1owQCADOMQSUYCAAtgmk9nIccDgALABMXnb1DYiBiABiMGCk6VkxCZTZ9u0A5mWaOABEAJIA5AWIBIj9Q2N1zW0dXWDZsX1QA2DDhqM1dY2NzQCiAEqXAPKXlFAAngAOpIhTNVOIMJmIYHA5TKZGCDMAEBJEN5QOCIJ6vd6LfZTPzNUIRWLEJKpDZbAAmeUKxVKh1QOA+1SmPGeBHsmVIEzAUBOpxZTSCNzSGU2MWEiIO5Sq1R4OAAHgSiiUZPJECKAHTQgDKuyGOGoK3ZnO6yB2e35RyFRjFf0JkrMMsQAGpEABGZkNC7XO4PF5vKb5CX2L4-P4AuZAkFgiFQmFw1185EBIJo8KIUgi55EGAQMKwl2ZHExQbiokjTh8njuom4cmUxDU2n0xknZocjOIcLZkq59D540e4ufYUiqUKbv0WwO273VPwqbh76-f6A4Gg8GQ2Ehl3vQslKZAA) using the following examples:

```
// Without callback
const a: number = foo(42);             // Fine
const b: string = foo("I'm a string"); // Fine
const c: string = foo(42);             // ERROR: type '42' is not assignable to type 'string'

// With callback
const d: number = foo('42', parseInt);                  // Ok
const e: string = foo(42, (x: number) => x.toString()); // Ok
const f: string = foo(42, (x: number) => x + 1);        // ERROR: type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'

// With explicit types
const g: number = foo<string, number>('42', parseInt);  // Ok
const h: number = foo<string, number>('42', (x) => x);  // ERROR: type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'
```