# Required and Partial with Array of Generics

Tags: typescript

I have these types:

```
interface Color {
  color: string
}

type DarkerColor<T> = T & Color & { darker: string }

type ColorInfo<T> = DarkerColor<T> & {
  hue: number
  luminance: number
  opacity?: number
}
```

and these functions:

```
function computeDarkerColor<T extends Color>(dataset: T[]): Array<DarkerColor<T>> {...}
function computeHueAndLuminance<T extends Color>(value: Array<DarkerColor<T>>): Array<ColorInfo<T>> {...}
function computeOpacity<T extends Color>(value: Array<ColorInfo<T>>): Array<Required<ColorInfo<T>>> {...}
```

So, basically, `computeHueAndLuminance` gets in input an object (array of objects) and returns another object (array of objects) that contanins the proprerties `hue` and `luminance`.
The function `computeOpacity` gets in input that object (array of objects) and returns the same objects (array of objects) with also the `opacity` property.

To do that I thought to use a single type `ColorInfo` with `hue` and `luminance` mandatory and `opacity` optional. Then use `Required` but it seems not to work. I tried also `Partial` in that way:

```
interface Color {
  color: string
}

type DarkerColor<T> = T & Color & { darker: string }

type ColorInfo<T> = DarkerColor<T> & {
  hue: number
  luminance: number
  opacity: number
}


function computeDarkerColor<T extends Color>(dataset: T[]): Array<DarkerColor<T>> {...}
function computeHueAndLuminance<T extends Color>(value: Array<DarkerColor<T>>): Array<Partial<ColorInfo<T>>> {...}
function computeOpacity<T extends Color>(value: Array<ColorInfo<T>>): Array<ColorInfo<T>> {...}
```

but I get the same error:

```
Type 'T & Color & { darker: string; } & { hue: number; luminance: number; opacity: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Required<ColorInfo<T>>'.
```

What is the problem?

Comment: I think that you passed a number to opacity instead of an optional string as suggested by typescript compiler.

Comment: @AntoineRaoulIscaros Sorry that was a typo, the error remains

Comment: Can you please show how you are using Partial ?

Comment: @AntoineRaoulIscaros Sure! I edited the main question

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505560/could-be-instantiated-with-a-different-subtype-of-constraint-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in [could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'object'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505560/could-be-instantiated-with-a-different-subtype-of-constraint-object)

you cannot modify the generic extended type.
One possible solution is to make the partial outside of the extended type.
In case you need a partial type that would work.

```
interface Color {
  color: string
}

type DarkerColor<T> = T & Color & { darker: string }

type ColorInfo<T> = DarkerColor<T> & Partial<{
  hue: number
  luminance: number
  opacity: number
}>


function computeDarkerColor<T extends Color>(dataset: T[]): Array<DarkerColor<T>> {...}
function computeHueAndLuminance<T extends Color>(value: Array<DarkerColor<T>>): Array<ColorInfo<T>> {...}
function computeOpacity<T extends Color>(value: Array<ColorInfo<T>>): Array<ColorInfo<T>> {...}
```

However to solve the issue of the 2 almost identical types you can use optional types or composition of any type for example Omit.

#### OMIT:

```
interface Color {
  color: string
}

type DarkerColor<T> = T & Color & { darker: string }

type ColorInfo<T> = DarkerColor<T> & {
  hue: number
  luminance: number
  opacity: number
}


function computeDarkerColor<T extends Color>(dataset: T[]): Array<DarkerColor<T>> {...}
function computeHueAndLuminance<T extends Color>(value: Array<DarkerColor<T>>): Array<Omit<ColorInfo<T>, 'opacity'>> {...}
function computeOpacity<T extends Color>(value: Array<ColorInfo<T>>): Array<ColorInfo<T>> {...}
```

Comment: Thank you Antoine but doing in that way I can't distinguish between the type that has `opacity` and the one that hasn't `opacity`, right?