# Error: Class is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint Class

Tags: typescript

I start saying that StackOverflow has plenty of questions about this error message, but none of them helped me, they are just different cases.

I'm trying to build a function that accepts a union type **A|B** and returns, accordingly, **A** or **B**.

An example is this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=24&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCYBdoG8BQ0PQLYFMD2A7gBQCUKAvupqHgHY6kBcciKVmmATjggK6e1o9AiwQBudtEqVUoSDAAieAOZsOBPHgBmpCpJr0m0JarQcO3PgKE4RJiR2mpUCAJ4AHHNACCtAJZYYCDQALyi0AA+xioSqFq8tMAIfnTQBjgAPAAq0DgAHgg4tAAmML4BQQB8RGD+gSDMWSSNaph+WtA1dUHQfrQQCLXA+B3wCGRm5hi1FSAAdLiEpA6Y5LkgEF7tnTP1vf2DiSPRyhOSHLtBcxray5KUFjz8gpfz6XeUQA):

```
class Cat {
    meow() {}
    clone(): Cat {
        return new Cat;
    }
}

class Dog {
    woof() {}
    clone(): Dog {
        return new Dog;
    }
}

type Animal = Cat | Dog;

function clone<T extends Animal>(animal: T): T {
    if (animal instanceof Cat) {
        animal.meow();
    } else if (animal instanceof Dog) {
        animal.woof();
    }
    return animal.clone();
}
```

But I receive the following error:

> Type 'Animal' is not assignable to type 'T'.   'Animal' is assignable
> to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a
> different subtype of constraint 'Animal'.
> Type 'Cat' is not assignable to type 'T'.
> 'Cat' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Animal'.

I expect to use it like:

```
const dog = new Dog();
const otherDog = clone(dog);
// otherDog's type is Dog and not Animal
```

I think the use of the keyword `extends` is wrong here, because I'm not supposed to extend a union type, but use one of the parts of the union type. But writing:

```
function clone(animal: Animal): Animal {
```

then the returned type is always `Animal`, and not `Dog` or `Cat`. I don't want explicitly assert the type.

How can I solve the problem?
Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'object'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505560/could-be-instantiated-with-a-different-subtype-of-constraint-object)

Comment: adding `return animal.clone() as T;` fixes the issue :)

Comment: @Ric thank you, it worked. Add it as an answer and I'll accept it