# Why can't I return a string literal type in TS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I don't understand the following error:

```
type Prefix = 'Ms' | 'Mrs' | 'Mr'

const broken = <T extends Prefix>(prefix: T): T => {
    // do something
    return 'Ms';  
 
    // If I do `return 'Ms' as 'Ms'` then it works

}

const works = <T extends Prefix>(prefix: T): T => {
    // do something
    return p;
}

const alsoWorks = (): Prefix => {
    // do something
    return 'Ms';
}
```

The method `broken` is giving me

> Type '"Ms"' is not assignable to type 'T'.   '"Ms"' is assignable to
> the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a
> different subtype of constraint 'Prefix'.

Not sure why this method doesn't work, but the other two do?

Comment: `works` does specifically `return prefix`, doesn't it? Or at least `p` is declared to be of type `T`.

Comment: "*If I do `return 'Ms' as 'Ms'` then it works*" - [it doesn't for me](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/C4TwDgpgBACgThAZgSwB5QLxQOQFkDO2UAPjrnISWXNgFC0DGA9gHb7BQBGcTA1hC0xQAPABUoEVMAEATfLAQpUAPgAUYRWgBcUUQEod4jMqgBvWlEtQA9NagymUfEwC2EYAAtkLAOYWrCMAArnCCeJQAhvLh2ADc9AC+9MxsHADuTHC88lhiElKy8vBIaGoaJaiGBrqYJuZWNnYOTq7uXr7+loEhguVK8UmMrOxQEQA2zgDqmdlCqtXFSrVmnY32js5unt5+Dd2hZIQDQA). Did you mean `return 'Ms' as T`? That would work around the type checker, but still be broken.

Comment: Here you can find an explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505560/could-be-instantiated-with-a-different-subtype-of-constraint-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript is complaining that the following call will not work:

```
const res: 'Mr' = broken<'Mr'>('Mr');
```

If `T` is instantiated to something else than `Ms`, your `return 'Ms'` is violating the the return type `T`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for -

```
broken<Prefix>('Ms')
```

or

```
broken('Ms' as Prefix)
```