# Type 'XX' is not assignable to type 'YY'. 'XX' is assignable to the constraint of type 'YY', but 'YY' could be instantiated

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-class

I got this error:

```ts
Type '{ [key: string]: any; }' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  '{ [key: string]: any; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{ [key: string]: any; }'.(2322)
```

from this piece of code:

```ts
function getValue ():{[key: string]: any}  {
    return {key:'value'}
}

class Foo<T extends {[key: string]: any}> {
    public readonly data?: T

    constructor() {
        this.data = getValue()
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why and how to solve this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'object' - ts(2322)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505560/could-be-instantiated-with-a-different-subtype-of-constraint-object-ts2322)

Comment: TLDR: What do you think the compiler should do if you pass `interface A { key: { sub: number } }` as the type parameter? This is exactly what it tells you: return type of `getValue` can differ from what `data` expects because there is *no direct relation* between `T` and `ReturnType<typeof getValue>`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to store a dictionary of items with type T? Then maybe this is what you want?:

```
function getValue ():{[key: string]: any}  {
    return {key:'value'}
}

class Foo<T> {
    public readonly data?: {[key: string]: T}

    constructor() {
        this.data = getValue()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler complains that you did not establish a direct relationship between the return type of the `getValue` function and the `data` instance property. `extends` clause only guarantees that *at a minimum* the generic type parameter is assignable to the provided constraint, but does not bound it otherwise.

Moreover, your `getValue` function returns a constant of type `{ key : 'value' }`. Therefore, when you assign the return type of a call to `getValue` to `this.data`, the compiler looks if the latter is a supertype of the former and sees that you only guaranteed `data` to be `{ [key: string]: any }`, or, in plain English:

> "some kind of object with any number of keys of type string and values of any type"

It should be obvious that `data` *can* have nothing in common with the `{ key : 'value' }` type. Now, take a look at what happens if you explicitly tell the compiler that `T` should conform to the return type of the `getValue` instead:

```ts
class Foo<T extends {[key: string]: any}> {
    public readonly data?: T | ReturnType<typeof getValue>;

    constructor() {
        this.data = getValue(); //OK
    }
}
```

Now the compiler is happy because it can establish the relationship, but you become limited to objects with single key `key` and values of type `string`. Frankly, from your snippet, it is unclear why do you need to make the class generic at all:

```ts
class Foo {
    public readonly data?: ReturnType<typeof getValue>;

    constructor() {
        this.data = getValue(); //OK
    }
}
```