# How to assign fixed type value to partial of generic constrained type?

Tags: typescript

I have a basic interface for things that may have Ids:

```js
interface Identifiable {
    id?: number;
}
```

And I have a generic function that converts a record object into a thing with id:

```js
function fromRowToObj1<T extends Identifiable>(row: { id: number; }): Partial<T> {
    return { id: row.id };
    // Type '{ id: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<T>'.
}
```

I understand that this happens because there are `T`s that extend `Identifiable` that would make that return statement illegal. For example, the type `{ id: undefined }` or `{ id: 1 }`. So I decided to tweak the return type a bit to enforce a numeric id:

```js
type Identified<T extends Identifiable> = {
    [K in keyof T]?: K extends "id" ? number : T[K];
}
// Should give something like type C = { id?: number | undefined; ... }

function fromRowToObj2<T extends Identifiable>(row: { id: number; }): Identified<T> {
    return { id: row.id };
    // Type '{ id: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Identified<T>'.
}
```

Why, though? Which possible `T` (such that `T extends Identifiable`) makes it so `{ id: number }` is not assignable to `Identified<T>`?

If there's no way to adjust the `Identified` type to make this work, is there another way to type the conversion function to work with generic subtypes of `Identifiable`?

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQEkAmVIjiBAIwBs0BvYVK1ETAfgC5UwBXAW0NgG5gBfYYHBZgkEEAHswqODHFsASuIDuAFXEB5QgCsAjAB4VqKAA9oYTAGcM2XPiKkAfAApZSpmRqYmrDt1S8ASiYABQQYMQRiAwdUCmpUGCgIFhgpD1omVwA6Wn8ePgFwaHhkNABpMGUwdGJSAHNIo1McS2scMTsSckpqDNRhbHwwKEwefmAIAE8ABzQsdrwQEYMms1b52wIumIBeWJ6qAG0ymikAayhJ8ThUFQBdRlQTkzWrACJaN9Q6ZnZOGFQTBUxzuYwEQhEYkk0lkCmUak0WgATCsXi0rBsOltHC5lO5PN4-n5AkxMYtlioYnFqIlkqlYgSEsocpg8gUJjM0ABBVB7Mn4ZbpLyoHT+Bw8KazVAAIV5bU2gsZAygQxGYolnNQAGE5fylpg9ELvFAAG6wdXAIA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are facing is thoroughly described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505560/how-to-fix-ts2322-could-be-instantiated-with-a-different-subtype-of-constraint). As you noticed yourself there are subtypes of `T extends Identifiable` which renders your return value `{ id: row.id }` invalid. For example `Identified<{id?: never}>` will never be valid for  `{ id: row.id }`. `Never` is still a valid type for `id` because you declared all keys of `Identified` as optional. `Identified<T>` is actually equal to `Partial<T>` if `T extends Identifiable`. Typescript correctly throws an error here. Though, you can still work around that if you set valid default values from which you can work onwards ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBMLmDYcBGANigN4BQylyw6A-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-HzNgAFigxCrmEsZFe4AA3FBwGMQOCJxRD5BwGRCDUEULmCHA8BuZBnxkNUFGUN0Vm0EMmSQZBW3NAw62RR4QAgN9BSDZAXw0ToYDjE4-HOIIrgg4hyS9CUs2lWVKHlRVlVVdVeH4LVqWKABmesdkNfZXA8NkMNrTt0EYO00gdGt+P7YN0GoGDCCsOAAE8ZD0TBcFw1SyKgNCJPbTC1ykJTJ19f0wEDSywGszdt2QXdc2QHiqz4qQABYhMbI1DnEs1zKkyJrRk5A5IUmlfOU5B8FEb8ZA4BA4GYaNIsSZ5oB4ZAADJMhoBgmDw6AsWQNE2haMB8qsYAw3-DTtJkBFZDK-DHPimzkGnANCKSr9VwRHqXMzbMPPzIaUuQIA)):

```
interface Identifiable {
    id?: number;
}

// results in optional id
function fromRowToObj1<T extends Identifiable>(row: { id: number; }) {
    const result: Partial<T> = {} // valid for all subtypes of Partial<T>
    result.id = row.id
    return result;
}

// results in non optional id
function fromRowToObj2<T extends Identifiable>(row: { id: number; } ) {
    const partial: Partial<T> = {}; // valid for all subtypes of Partial<T>
    const result = {
        ...partial,
        id: row.id
    };
    return result;
}

interface TestObject {
    id: number,
    arg1: string;
    arg2: boolean;
}

const result1 = fromRowToObj1<TestObject>({id: 5});
result1.id // optional
result1.arg1 = "test" // intellisense works
result1.arg2 = true; // intellisense works

const result2 = fromRowToObj2<TestObject>({id: 5});
result2.id // not optional
result2.arg1 = "test" // intellisense works
result2.arg2 = true; // intellisense works
```

Comment: As long as id from Identifiable is optional, these workarounds have types that can break them. I've posted an example for such a type in the playground. But these are types that probably won't be used anyway.

Comment: The playground says that `Identifiable<{ id?: never}>` is `{ id?: number | undefined}`, though. So why isn't `{ id: number }` assignable to it?

Comment: Anyway, your second example with non-optional id works perfectly. With that I can type the return type as `Partial<T> & { id: number }` which is what I wanted. It does feel kinda weird to have to go through that hoop.