# Infer type based on input structure

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm struggling with inferring type based upon input parameters. Basically I want to use the structure of an object to infer the return type (although not just the . I think the trick is to use a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) but I can't get it to work:

```
type Active = { name: string; active: true };
type Inactive = { name: string; active: false };
type IdWithAct = Active | Inactive;

export const getIdWithType = <
  Arg extends IdWithAct,
  T extends Arg extends Active ? 'ActiveItem' : 'InactiveItem'
>({
  name,
  active,
}: IdWithAct): {name: string, typeName: T } =>  ({
    name,
    typeName: active ? 'ActiveItem' : 'InactiveItem',
  });
```

See [playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIEEDGoCWA3OBeWBvWA7AQwFtoAuWAZ1ACcV8BzAblkOXXNloFc4BfJmChwAkkXYZY2PEVIVqdRizaoMFAGaEANpX6CIMWCIAmAdRSgAFklBSEEuAB8j41dEHBoAD0gB7GraIvvjUsAzQoABiNIQMAHIk0PD4xibRvsQ2HHYAPMCwCDQMsN6g0CmURmYW1sgANPmwAColXmUVhcWl5caVWZIA-LAA5P3QImXEw7AUw2IqHBPQU8AAfAAUOI2y0A0FCxgNfBQm5lY2AJQUODvytPQMdVzCCXLNsHxSqwWbjQU7ewKzxgr04BzgQ1GDiWUxmI3m0Mmw0BfAuTCAA). I've looked at the `infer` solutions but the examples are too trivial for what (at least I think) I'm trying to accomplish...

### Edit

Added examples from the comments.

#### Overloading

As suggested by the comments there is the overloading option, unfortunately TypeScript seems to have issues with calling the function within another:

```
type ActivityWithName<T> = { name: string, active: T}
type IdWithAct = ActivityWithName<true> | ActivityWithName<false>;

type Types = 'ActiveItem' | 'InactiveItem'
type Ret<T> = { name: string, typeName: Types }

function getFragNameAndIdFromActive(args: ActivityWithName<true>): Ret<'ActiveItem'>
function getFragNameAndIdFromActive(args: ActivityWithName<false>): Ret<'InactiveItem'>
function getFragNameAndIdFromActive<Arg extends IdWithAct>({
  name,
  active,
}: IdWithAct): Ret<Types> {
  return  {
    name,
    typeName: active ? 'ActiveItem' : 'InactiveItem',
  }
}

const retActive = getFragNameAndIdFromActive({ name: 'activeItem', active: true })
const retInactive = getFragNameAndIdFromActive({ name: 'activeItem', active: false })

function test(active: boolean) {
  // active complaints: Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'false'.
  const ret = getFragNameAndIdFromActive({ name: 'activeItem', active })
}
```

See [playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIEEDGoCWA3FEDqmAWA5AQwFtoAeAFQD5YBeWAb1gDsToAuWAZ1ACcVmAcwA0sQsnQdYFAL5gocAJIATHKFxJQdBBIzY8RUmT4BXaDQA+O1HvBqCbMgDNCAGy7mA3CAgxpCrm0Ack1JRVBoYiDYKyDFVl1ocMig+T8AJWhQShp6JlZSTh5+IVFfaEMpCgDYOWAnE2YJAHtmWEEsgDFeQkFK+GZlFW7m4lC0aAAKQl5BLk5xzDsDR1NzAEpOTOyQxOSoqnrGlraO0G7e-sHh3lHxqZm5hd0l+0rnNw8qTdhtsjiEjYkhEDkcmqhWu0uj0+mwBkNlCMxokyPBZrBoAAPCKDQIqeyaKiTBjAWAsNjCUliRKUmScfF4TQ-P7VGBcGgksm8LImXhtRhUskFaCUslk8qVTjiIGwAD8sF2QP20U4AOlYRBQVFtWAdUQrR4sG5oHu2jOF1hpHhNzuiWJ5MKCvVE2VomdUjWtXWwH1zENxvi7rN0MucOuiNuyKB9uFqvdrupQM4LnccBk3rBJ1gER400SnAARs1mq5oIRmOsBWTff6ssHzjCrgikfcY2w43tNW7El7dcAgA). The solution is appealing as it is rather explicit with the intentions of the overloadning.

#### Runtime assertion

The suggestion with the runtime assertion works but it is in my opinion a little too magic and if the return object is different by more than a single value it could very well become rather messy:

```
type IdWithAct<T> = { name: string; active: T };
type Status<T> = T extends true ? 'ActiveItem' : 'InactiveItem'

export const getIdWithType = <T extends boolean>({
    name,
    active,
}: IdWithAct<T>) => ({
    name,
    typeName: (active ? 'ActiveItem' : 'InactiveItem') as Status<T>,
});

const foo = getIdWithType({ name: 'x', active: true }) // { name: string; typeName: "ActiveItem"; }
const bar = getIdWithType({ name: 'x', active: false }) // { name: string; typeName: "InactiveItem"; }

const test = (active: boolean) => getIdWithType({ name: 'x', active })
```

Comment: Only with type assertion because generics can be resolved only when calling the function, not within it https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgJgdQJbABYEEDGwA8AVAPigF4oBvKAOwEMBbCALigGdgAnJSgcwG4prsSAG6MoeKAF8eAKFCQoAZWDVgAV2b4ipcRAAewCJTjMo7VdAD8UAORZgwiDAO1rUJtZg1BIpxBfTpPTAAezZgKExgylYoLghgeGQ0PHBoUnwoPQMjEwAjYOCAGwhqSgIACjJpKBqqOggAGmragXsRJokmRJQMbE0AShIiSuaamnom2tNUgDl6pnLWhygrW29HZ1d3TyWfTcHqEyUVdU0O-plpSOjwgDMCklj47uTUyrr6d11rBv51pjM0AkgwA9CDyB9RKwONw+HIIHNPlAAER2By+WjIvgSK5RGK5ahsR5xBKIHopSDvcaiazfX67US3aiFZhA0HgijUpjQzi8aaQRGiZE7dYYrGSIA

Comment: Try to write overloads

Comment: @captain-yossarian - overloads look appealing but I can't get them to work properly, see my update to the question.

Comment: You may be facing this issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505560/how-to-fix-ts2322-could-be-instantiated-with-a-different-subtype-of-constraint

Comment: W.R>T above comment you can check this - https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgN2gXigbygOwIYC2EAXFAM7ABOiOA5gNxR4IolRUCu0AvvQFChI5eElRQM2ZqLace-QdACS+FmIm5CbCtTqMprUgDM8AGzJyB4JQBMA6omAALEeNiroAHyjL9qfnzgAexwKKFoIYAAxSjxaADlNGBxrRWtowIIRVlcAHj4oWEpaKAgAD2AIZLJvOwdnBAAafKgAFRLyyutqmCL2iqq3aSgAfigAcizURQqCMahSMZ93aYhZvgA+AApMZvwiJoLfCCbuUlT7JxEASlIdgr2tKhoGZoUEolI2rwnlmbnvpbSFazfjccTrKDbXaaA7sKzvNhHEbjSYQYFzBaA1jok5XfxBEKBEwQAB0JkCtE24SiMXiiWSqXSmXc2w0H3GswaTHcRlM5ig3CueL4QA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add one more overload:

```js
type ActivityWithName<T> = { name: string, active: T}
type IdWithAct = ActivityWithName<boolean>

type Types = 'ActiveItem' | 'InactiveItem'
type Ret<T extends Types> = { name: string, typeName: T } // use generic parameter

function getFragNameAndIdFromActive<T extends true>(args: ActivityWithName<T>): Ret<'ActiveItem'>
function getFragNameAndIdFromActive<T extends false>(args: ActivityWithName<T>): Ret<'InactiveItem'>
function getFragNameAndIdFromActive(args: ActivityWithName<boolean>): Ret<Types> // less specific overload
function getFragNameAndIdFromActive({
  name,
  active,
}: IdWithAct): Ret<Types> {
  return  {
    name,
    typeName: active ? 'ActiveItem' : 'InactiveItem',
  }
}

const retActive = getFragNameAndIdFromActive({ name: 'activeItem', active: true })
const retInactive = getFragNameAndIdFromActive({ name: 'activeItem', active: false })

function test(active: boolean) {
  const ret = getFragNameAndIdFromActive({ name: 'activeItem', active }) // ok
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIEEDGoCWA3FEDqmAWA5AQwFtoAeAFQD5YBeWAb1gDsToAuWAZ1ACcVmAcwA0sQsnQdYFAL5gocAJIATHKFxJQdBBIzY8RUmQBGAe1MAbaIWZUQEGNIVdtAck2TFoaMVewAPrCuiqy60F4%20rvKOAErQoJSw0AAe3szKLhTONPRMrKScPPxCog7QhlIUsHLAAGYArswSpsywgvEAYryEghXw6SpdpsQeaORVKWkZsHz10FQAFIS8glyco5jgagRslFQAlJxxCe5hEb52DU2oLW2d3b1s-cqDvMOj40mp0OkutYQWLjzJYrNY6VB6LYGXbUQ6wY5kYKhCHhbwXOqNZqtdqgLo9PoDZRDEZhEGrda6TbbComcxWGwHI7xSjZDHXFC3HF4x6kZ6vd6khjAWAsNjCYViMLimScFTbTRwhFZGBcGhCkW8eL1XitRgSkX5aDikUisoVTjiFGwAD8QQ%205z8nCRls8aNcxuqwBqiBaPFgmtAH20XIeBJeRLeJJRCzybCdLrGDtECakszgMn2wB9zD9AZCKeD93xT0JxI%20MdFBSCKaTkpRnH%20gPTmbZWJm0B4SzCnDMlmszH2epF2dz8ULuNDJfDZcFlakrhrbuTYWqg4A9GvYKYANZe4BAA)