# Function to rename key in Typescript fails with "could be instantiated with a different subtype" error?

Tags: typescript

I have a type `Mongoify` that takes in a type `T` and removes the `id` key and replaces it with a `_id` key.

```js
type Mongoify<T extends {id: string}> = Omit<T, "id"> & {
    _id: ObjectId
};

function fromMongo<T extends { id: string }>(x: Mongoify<T>): T {
    const { _id, ...theRest } = x;
    const  withNormalId = { ...theRest, id: _id.toHexString() };
    return withNormalId
}
```

For some reason, this function does not type check. I get the error:

```
Type 'Omit<Mongoify<T>, "_id"> & { id: string; }' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'Omit<Mongoify<T>, "_id"> & { id: string; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{ id: string; }'.(2322)
```

I have looked at [How to fix TS2322: "could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'object'"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505560/how-to-fix-ts2322-could-be-instantiated-with-a-different-subtype-of-constraint), which explains what is going on with this error. But I'm not sure what the cause is here. My assumption is Typescript is failing to do the type inference that `...theRest` is of type `Omit<Mongoify<T>, "_id">`, but even that seems incorrect because if I mouse over the value in the playground, Typescript shows me the correct type.

Anyone know why this function is failing to typecheck?

Comment: in more generic form it looks like ```Type 'Pick<T, K> & Omit<T, K>' is not assignable to type 'T'```

Comment: What's `ObjectId`?  Please consider modifying the code to be a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NlpJlN) which demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are literal types in typescript and thus it cannot guarantee the returned type `T` will match your type 'Omit<Mongoify, "_id"> & { id: string; }`. For example if you have

```ts
type Bad = { id: 'literal-string' }
```

You'd expect the result of:

```ts
fromMongo<Bad>({ _id: objectId })
```

be of type `Bad` but in fact your runction implementation returns type `{ id: string }`.

To mitigate this ussue you can rewrite your function as:

```ts
function fromMongo<
    T extends { _id: ObjectId }
>(x: T): Omit<T, '_id'> & { id: string } {
    const { _id, ...theRest } = x;

    return  { ...theRest, id: _id.toHexString() };
}
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wjJb2w)