# TS: How do I type an arrow function with a parameter that has a default value?

Tags: javascript, typescript

How do I type an arrow function with a parameter that has a default value?
before in javascript, it is a function that accepts a boolean value and when it is not provided it defaults to `false`

```js
const foo = (initial = false) =>
```

now I rewrote this function into TS and expand the param to be able to get a function that returns a boolean,

```
const foo = <T extends boolean>(initial: T | (() => T)) =>
```

Now the problem is that I still need to make `initial` default to `false` when it is not provided. How can I do that in TS? I tried a few but it doesn't pass the TS compiler.

For example

```
const foo = <T extends boolean>(initial = false: T | (() => T)) =>
```

will be a syntax error in TS

Comment: Is there a reason you are using Generics here, why not Boolean. Also, What value would you want to return when a non boolean value is used?

Comment: You need to specify the default value after the type: `initial: T | (() => T)  = false`

Comment: @KrisztiánBalla this might not work. false can't be a value for all types of `T`. Using Generics is a problem here.

Comment: Generics and default values don't play well together, as others have said, because you cannot know that `false` is assignable to `T`.  Why not `const foo = (initial: boolean | (() => boolean) = false) =>` as in [this](https://tsplay.dev/WPjxLN)?  If you really need generics, please consider modifying your question to include a [mcve] that gives clear criteria for accepting/rejecting an answer.  For example, it would be helpful if you would provide an implementation and/or return type annotation for `foo` that uses `T` in a plausible way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix TS2322: "could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'object'"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505560/how-to-fix-ts2322-could-be-instantiated-with-a-different-subtype-of-constraint)

Answer (score 1):

There's no obvious need for this to be a generic function. So let's make your life a lot easier.

The syntax you want is:

```
argName: ArgType = defaultValue
```

Or in your case:

```
initial: boolean | (() => boolean) = false
```

Full example:

```
const foo = (initial: boolean | (() => boolean) = false) => () => initial
console.log(foo()()) // false
console.log(foo(true)()) // true
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MAUBLMGoYIYA2AXDAEaIECmeYMAPumgJQoB8ZF1YLqchElHu2ZsYWHPgIAoKaEggqAOgIgA5mgQhmzFgHpd8fpVngICysrUbEaKACcAroJ0x9Me06lA)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assing a concrete value to a generic , In typescript, a concrete instance is not allowed to be assigned to a type parameter.

Refer to this answer for detail

[How to fix TS2322: "could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'object'"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505560/how-to-fix-ts2322-could-be-instantiated-with-a-different-subtype-of-constraint)