# Fully static HOC in react and typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this code:

```
type AAdds = {
  name: string
}
type WithAAdds<T> = T & Partial<AAdds>

const withMyHoc = function<P>(Wrapped: FC<WithAAdds<P>>) {
  return (props: P) => {
    return (
      <Wrapped name="john" {...props} />
    )
  }
}

const MyComponent = ({name, lastName}: {name:string, lastName: string}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {name} : {lastName}
    </div>
  )
}

const MyHocComponent = withMyHoc(MyComponent)

const App = () => {
  // Property 'name' is missing in type '{ lastName: string; }' but required in type '{ name: string; lastName: string; }'.ts(2741)
  return <MyHocComponent lastName="Doe" />
}
```

I want the `<MyHocComponent />` to be statically typed and without listing `name` in vs code. Is this possible?

I tried adding this additional type:

```
type WithoutAAdds<T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof AAdds, 'name'>>
```

And setting the HOC's return type to `FC<WithoutAAdds<P>>`, but that fails too with

```
Type '(props: P) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'FC<WithoutAAdds<P>>'.
  Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
    Type 'PropsWithChildren<WithoutAAdds<P>>' is not assignable to type 'P'.
      'P' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'PropsWithChildren<WithoutAAdds<P>>'.ts(2322)
```

This comes from the return signature `(props: P)`.

Comment: IDK, But i think `Exclude` track is ok (however i would use `Omit`.
Maybe this elaborate can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505560/how-to-fix-ts2322-could-be-instantiated-with-a-different-subtype-of-constraint

Comment: You should not only add it to the return type, but to the `props` type as well. `function<P>(Wrapped: FC<WithAAdds<P>>): FC<Omit<P, keyof WithAAdds<P>>> { return (p: Omit<P, keyof WithAAdds<P>>) => ... }`

Comment: @AlexChashin then `cannot assign "name"` blah blah is the typescript error to the `<Wrapped>`

Answer (score 0):

So "fully static" does not seem to be possible. Perhaps someone can improve this, but it does address the original problem:

1. The `<Wrapped>` is statically listing the `name`, but removing this property does not show the error message in vs code (nay :( ).
2. The `<MyHocComponent>` properly lists `lastName` and no `name`. Removing `lastName` does give an error in vs code (yay!).

The only roadblock to a "fully static" HOC is the `any` for the inner props. I could not find a workaround to make that statically typed. The first observation above seems to stem from this roadblock.

PS: Thanks to @Zbigniew Zagórski and @Alex Chashin for `Omit` type.

```
type AAdds = {
  name: string
}
type WithAAdds<T> = T & AAdds
type WithoutAAdds<T> = Omit<T, keyof AAdds>

const withMyHoc = function <P>(Wrapped: FC<WithAAdds<P>>): FC<WithoutAAdds<P>> {
  return (props: any) => {
    return (
      <Wrapped name="john" {...props} />
    )
  }
}

const MyComponent = ({ name, lastName }: { name: string, lastName: string }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {name} : {lastName}
    </div>
  )
}

const MyHocComponent = withMyHoc(MyComponent)

const App = () => {
  return <MyHocComponent lastName="Doe" />
}
```

Comment: replacing `any` with `WithAAdds<P>` yields the original problem with inference of `P` and subtypes.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I did was copy and paste your code into the TypeScript Playground.  By hovering over `withMyHoc(MyComponent)` I can see the inferred type for `P` is `{name: string; lastName: string}`.  But we want `P` to be `{lastName: string}` only, and for `name` to be added by `WithAAdds`.

So then I tried to see if it would work I explicitly set the value for `P` rather than letting it be inferred.  Like this:

```
const MyHocComponent = withMyHoc<{lastName: string}>(MyComponent)
```

This revealed your first error.  `T & Partial<AAdds>` says the `name` property is optional on the outer component because of the `Partial`.  This won't work because `MyComponent` requires `name`.

**You need to make the added properties be requirements.**

```
type WithAAdds<T> = T & AAdds
```

This is progress, because now the above code where we manually specified `withMyHoc<{lastName: string}>` will work, and `name` won't be required in `MyHocComponent`.

You can also do this:

```
const MyHocComponent = withMyHoc<{lastName: string}>(({name, lastName}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {name} : {lastName}
    </div>
  )
})
```

But we still aren't getting the proper type inference.

---

The `Exclude`/`Omit` approach (`Omit` uses `Exclude` under the hood) allows for automatic type inference of `P`, but it introduces a possibility for an edge case problem where `P` could be `{name: "Bob", lastName: string}`.  That's why you get the dreaded "could be instantiated with an arbitrary type" error.

If you want to ignore that edge case, you can just assert correctness.

```
const withMyHoc = function<P extends AAdds>(Wrapped: FC<P>) {
  return (props: Omit<P, keyof AAdds>) => {
    return (
      <Wrapped {...{...props, name: "john"} as P} />
    )
  }
}
```

This version is more readable, but less precise, since we are asserting that `props` is `P` when we know that it isn't because it's missing the name.

```
const withMyHoc = function<P extends AAdds>(Wrapped: FC<P>) {
  return (props: Omit<P, keyof AAdds>) => {
    return (
      <Wrapped {...props as P} name="john" />
    )
  }
}
```