# Unable to assign props due to Typescripts nature of generics

Tags: reactjs, typescript, type-inference, typescript-generics

In this case I'm trying to make a HOC that would take control of a component that can't function without it.

**In more detail:** a HOC that takes a component that expects props `value` and `onChange` and returns a component that no longer expects those props, because they are taken care of.

This is what I got so far:

```
interface ControlledInput {
    value: string
    onChange: (newValue: string) => void
}

function withControl<T extends ControlledInput>(Elem: FC<T>){

    return (props: Omit<T, keyof ControlledInput>) => {

        const [value, setValue] = React.useState('')

        return <Elem value={value} onChange={setValue} {...props} /> // error
    }
}
```

However typescript gives me an error that props I'm passing to `Elem` are not assignable to type T. [Link to codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-https-9e1c2?file=/src/App.tsx).

The error I get is discussed and explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59363875/12850467). TL;DR: *Never assign concrete types to generic parameter, consider it read-only.* Ironic that this conclusion is stated as **solution**. That's not a solution, I **need** to assign these props.

I've tried not using generic at all, but than prop types of a resulting component are lost.

Type casting helps but isn't it the same as putting `any` everywhere? If I just wanted to not see red squiggly lines I would use JavaScript

```
function withControl<T extends ControlledInput>(Elem: FC<T>) {
    return (props: Omit<T, keyof ControlledInput>) => {

        const [value, setValue] = React.useState('')

        return <Elem {...{ value, onChange: setValue, ...props } as T} /> // error is gone
    }
}
```

In ideal world I would like to tell TypeScript that I only care that component passed as `Elem` has props `value`, `onChange` and whatever else (the T). And resulting component expects as props what is left (the T). That's it, not very difficult on paper yet really difficult to describe to TS.

Comment: You really don't need to use generic `T` for this scenario. Just use `FC<ControlledInput>`

Comment: could you please provide an example, where prop types of component passed as argument carry over to resulting component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error:

```
  'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{ value: string; onChange: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>; }'.ts(2322)
```

is correct.

Consider this example:

```js
interface ControlledInput {
  value: string;
  onChange: (newValue: string) => void;
}

interface FooProps {
  value: string;
  onChange: (newValue: string) => void;
  name: "hello";
}

const Foo: FC<FooProps> = () => null;

const withControl = <T extends ControlledInput>(Elem: FC<T>) => () =>
  // props: Omit<T, keyof ControlledInput>
  {
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState("");

    return <Elem value={value} onChange={setValue} />;
  };

withControl(Foo);
```

`FooProps` is a subtype of `ControlledInput`. This line `withControl(Foo)` compiles. But you ended up in a situation where `Foo` has required prop `name` whereas you have provided only `value` and `onChange`.

In order to fix it, just get rid of generic:

```js
interface ControlledInput {
  value: string;
  onChange: (newValue: string) => void;
}

interface FooProps {
  value: string;
  onChange: (newValue: string) => void;
  name: "hello";
}

const Foo: FC<FooProps> = () => null;

const withControl = (Elem: FC<ControlledInput>) => () =>
  // props: Omit<T, keyof ControlledInput>
  {
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState("");

    return <Elem value={value} onChange={setValue} />;
  };

withControl(Foo); // expected error
```

---

**SAFE FIX**

> could you please provide an example, where prop types of component passed as argument carry over to resulting component

You can use this pattern:

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react'


interface MainProps {
  value: string;
  onChange: (value: string) => void
  name: string;
}

type ControlProps = {
  children: (value: string, setValue: (value: string) => void) => JSX.Element
}

const Control: FC<ControlProps> = ({ children }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');

  return children(value, setValue)
}

const Foo = (props: MainProps) => <div></div>;


const App =() => {
  <Control>{
    (value, onChange) =>
      <Foo value={value} onChange={onChange} name='hello' />
  }
  </Control>
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBiAwnAL5wBmUEIcA5FKhrQFCvAB2MSU56ScAWRQcAClTABnXMzhwAbigA2AVyQAuOBJhQOAcwDcMuBHaEAFina71cABQKVNrTqsBKOAF4AfPIjAAJkbsKCBO2nqGJKwwAJ5g-IQm2hCKYhCSntKyaGbAiv4M7Br2SqoaznrYEkgwAGqlNiWO5eFunj5yfv7u3nAAUgDKABoAdACiikihnMxRzGgmWnCJnFSKGkQAPCvJqeISPh52eDl5BUjspD0%20OEYL7EsA2g6qVTX1jgC6mcjoMCPKaoDGAoLi2Wi0VyGIwMGDKKCXU75QpNV6ad4NVyzVj3Jb4CAQTK2MD7DRCUT7a5wTb%20YByLybAD0tPp0Pmi3gAEEwGBPLYqbdZNskmsvILZHYXkhsCZzJZrNcjBLqfjCVKPDgpWRZRYrEgNTr5UgyMFQh5aGYkIpFBBaHBGV4jFEhYydqLZkA)

**UNSAFE FIX**

If you still want to stick with your approach, you can turn off this flag:`strictFunctionTypes`.

In general it is unsafe what you are trying to do. Consider this example:
You can override `value & onChange` in `T` and intersect it back with `ControlledInput`, like here:

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react'


type ControlledInput = {
  value: string;
  onChange: (newValue: string) => void;
}

interface FooProps {
  value: string;
  onChange: (newValue: string) => void;
}

const Foo: FC<FooProps> = (props) => null;

type Keys = 'value' | 'onChange';

const withControl = <T extends ControlledInput>(
  Elem: FC<Omit<T, Keys> & ControlledInput>
) =>
  <Props extends Omit<T, keyof ControlledInput>>(props: Props) => {
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState("");

    return <Elem value={value} onChange={setValue} {...props} />;
  };

withControl(Foo)({ name: 'hellow' }); // ok
```

This code compiles, but once you add extra property to `Foo`, it will fail. Because TypeScript checks arguments from left to right. In this case, we ended up with similar error: `FooProps` type is assignable to `ControlledInput` but not vice versa because `FooProps` is a subtype.

If you want to make it work, you should use explicit generic argument. I'm not a huge fan of this technique but is seems that it is the only reasonable way to solve this issue:

```js
type ControlledInput = {
  value: string;
  onChange: (newValue: string) => void;
}

interface FooProps {
  value: string;
  onChange: (newValue: string) => void;
  name: string;
}

const Foo: FC<FooProps> = (props) => null;

type Keys = 'value' | 'onChange';

const withControl = <T extends ControlledInput>(
  Elem: FC<Omit<T, Keys> & ControlledInput>
) =>
  <Props extends Omit<T, keyof ControlledInput>>(props: Props) => {
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState("");

    return <Elem value={value} onChange={setValue} {...props} />;
  };

withControl<FooProps>(Foo)({ name: 'hello' }); // ok
```

Comment: No, in my case prop `name` would be provided in `{...props}`, your implementation looses `name` entirely and resulting component has no props. Line you commented out is important

Comment: Ohh, my bad. I missed that part :D

Comment: @Alexl. made an update

Comment: It's a working example, sure, but not for the problem I was trying to solve, sorry if my explanation was unclear and thanks for your work

Comment: @Alexl. made an update

Comment: It's insane how difficult it is to implement this hoc so it works correctly. Thanks

Comment: @Alexl. you will get used to it

Answer (score 0):

I did some experiments, apparently it's a TypeScript's limitation:

```
interface Foo {
    value: string
    name: string
    num: number
}

function test<T extends Foo>(data: T){

      let {value, ...rest} = data

      let t: T = {value, ...rest} // same error
}
```

It thinks that `{value: string} & Omit<T, 'value'>` and `T` are not the same. And honestly, I don't understand why.

Yet, when dealing with concrete types it works as expected

```
let foo: Foo = {name: '', value: '', num: 0}

let {num, ...rest} = foo

let foo2: Foo = {num, ...rest} // no error
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQDED2nUG9iqGoBuCANgK5QBcqAzhDOAOYFFgIC2N9jLbhMBU60hnAEaxgAX2DA4FMEgghMYVNAYAeACqooAD2hgAJnQzYAfAAoTCCAlo6AlPgFEyUCHlKUoAGlQAOhCYKAZpVABeVDsHOSIPLw0naJ9yKkCQoLCImTlPbzhsWiwcGNwObloAchrA3ypa%20tQxWgAGWWBCvDEs0PCISJjizALk8QQAL1LsNMrhfpzB6SA)

Type casting it is than.