# TypeScript type inference from default parameter of type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-constraints

Given the following example:

```js
interface Foo {
  name: string;
}

interface Bar extends Foo {
  displayName: string;
}

const foo: Foo = { name: "foo" };
const bar: Bar = { name: "bar", displayName: "dn" };

const getName = <T extends Foo>(obj: T = foo): string => {
  return obj.name;
};

getName(foo); // Ok
getName(bar); // Ok
```

`obj: T = foo` causes an error. Even though, `T extends Foo`, this is not accepted. Why is this the case and what would be an workaround?

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-forked-e03gw?file=/src/index.ts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `foo` is not of type `T`, suppose if you want to instantiate the generic with the interface `Bar`:

```
const getName = (obj: Bar = foo): string => {
  return obj.name;
};
```

You can see that `foo` is not a `Bar` (is missing the `displayName` property) and you can't assign it to a variable of type `Bar`.

You have now three options:

1. Force `foo` to be used as a generic `T`: `<T extends Foo>(obj: T = foo as T): string => ...`. But this is the worst choiche you could do (could lead to unexpected results/errors).
2. Overloading your function to match your generic specifications. This is useful if you need to return (and actually use) your generic instance:

```
const getName: {
  // when you specify a generic on the function
  // you will use this overload
  <T extends Foo>(obj: T): T;

  // when you omit the generic this will be the overload
  // chosen by the compiler (with an optional parameter)
  (obj?: Foo): Foo;
}
= (obj: Foo = foo): string => ...;
```

3. Notice that your function does not use at all the generic and pass the parameter as a simple `Foo`: `(obj: Foo = foo): string => ...`. This should be the best one in your case

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a [Generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) for your `getName` function and can use a type annotation of `Foo` for the input parameter `obj`, i.e.:

```
const getName = (obj: Foo = foo): string => {
  return obj.name;
};
```

This is because in Typescript every complex type (e.g. objects and arrays) is **covariant** in its members.

In other words: Since TypeScript knows that `Foo` here has less required fields and therefore `Bar` is a subtype of `Foo` any element of type `Bar` will be accepted by the `getName` function. That is, you can safely use a `Bar` anywhere a `Foo` is required. (As noted by @DDomen in the comment, function parameter types behave differently)

Let me explain **covariance**:

- Although you assign the type `Foo` to `obj` it will also work for `getName(bar);` because `Bar extends Foo` (and thereby `Bar` is a subtype of `Foo`).
- This is allowed because of the way the Typescript engineers set up the type system. They decided that members of objects (i.e. complex types like shapes and arrays) should be allowed to receive its defined type and anything which is a subtype of that type.
- In type theory this behavior can be described as shapes being **covariant** in its members.
- Other type systems don't allow such flexibility, i.e. to use a subtype in such a situation. Such type systems would then by called **invariant** on members of a shape because they'd require exactly the type `Foo` and would not allow for this flexibility which TypeScript allows.
- Also note that `Bar` does not have to explicitly extend `Foo` because TypeScript is structurally typed. TypeScript compares the structure of two objects to see whether one is the sub- or supertype of the other. So instead of `interface Bar extends Foo` you could also just define `Bar` as:

  ```
  interface Bar {
    name: string;
    displayName: string;
  }
  ```

  and `getName` will still be properly typed with its parameter `obj` as `Foo`.

**When to use generics**?

You don't need a generic because you don't want to relate different parts of your function to each other. A valid use of a generic may be if you want to relate your input parameter to your output parameter.

See this [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIhwC2EAXMgM5hSgDmA3LgL666iSyIoBCcUyCAA9IIACaU0mHPmRjglAA4AbOAE8AciXJUa9Jq1wJ0IashiYKGLAF4chbRQBEF9E+TMmx02GQAjfgo+ATtsB1JnAKgnABo5BRV1LQjkJzEQd082bzM6CDBklDsACnQ-ACsya2Q7VwBKCmpaEDoagD4ZAih8gFcoEGQy8oA6IlIDJlw8gu1i+oZkAHpF5AB5AGsp-MLiqLqF5bXNoA) of your code.

See also [this related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56505560/3210677) concerning the error you're getting, i.e.

```
Type 'Foo' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'Foo' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Foo'.(2322)
```

Comment: The link points to an incomplete file

Comment: @Vivere Sorry, fixed the link

Comment: Care, typescript is not *covariant* itself, but all the user defined types in typescript are (variance is a property of the type, not of the language). Also here you have one of the few cases of *contravariance* in typescript, because `getName` is a function. Indeed, resuming our example, you could assign a function with signature `(obj: Foo) => '1' | '2'` to a variable  of signature `(obj: Bar) => string`, which match the definition of contravariance: A type `T` is *contravariant* if having `S <: P`, then `T<P> <: T<S>` (`Bar <: Foo` then `Function<Foo> <: Function<Bar>`, `<:` means subtype)

Comment: @DDomen Thanks, I changed the formulation of the first sentence. Indeed, function types are contravariant  in its parameter types in TS. 
However, if I have a function `getName` with type `(obj: Foo = foo): string` it will accept an object of type `Bar` as its argument if `Bar <: Foo` (where `<:` means subtype). 
Isn't this (i.e. the fact that I can provide a value of type `Bar` where a value of its supertype `Foo` is expected) the definition of covariance or am I mislead? 

I just recently learned about variance. I very much appreciate your thorough comment!

Comment: @Andru sorry for the late, busy period. Your correction is right. What you are mentioning is subtyping, where you can assign an object of type `Bar` to a variable of type `Foo` (given `Bar <: Foo`). Variance describes subtyping for generic types, so ansewer the question "Which is the relation between `MyType<Foo>` and `MyType<Bar>`?". In TS all the user defined types are **covariant**, so `MyType<Bar> <: MyType<Foo>`, only exceptions are functions, which are **contravariant** (`Func<Foo> <: Func<Bar>`). It means you can do `var f: (p: Bar) => ... = (p: Foo) => ...` but not `var f: Foo = Bar`

Comment: @DDomen Thanks again. Should I adapt my answer and scrape my description of covariance because it is not relevant here? In the book “Programming TypeScript” (from Boris Cherny) I read on page 117: “When talking about types, we say that TypeScript shapes (objects and classes) are covariant in their property types.” - This made me believe that variance is a general way to describe subtype and supertype relationships in type theory and can therefore not only be used for parametrized (generic) types, but also as an explanation of why the type I suggest here works?!

Comment: @Andru no it is ok to talk of covariance here, because typescript uses structural subtyping (it checks the members of a structure instead of its raw type). What Boris Cherny is saying is related to structural typing, the covariance in this case is referred to the members of a type. Let's take `type Foo = { v1: number, v2: string }` as example, you can describe it as a parametrized type in non-structural subtyping fashion: `Foo = Object<[ [ 'v1', number ], [ 'v2', string ] ]>` (with `Object<Array<[Key, Value]>>` is the JS object type checker). Now you can apply the usual variance properties.

Comment: Variance is an extension of subtyping, so its appliance really depends on the type system. Indeed, variance also affects multiple inheritance (in those languages which support it, like c++) and the method overriding behaviour (also in TS). In those languages that does not support these features, you can (almost always) achieve these by the mean of generics. So, at the end of all, we could refer to variance as a parametrized type property. Do you agree?