# In TypeScript, how to reference the implementing class from an interface?

Tags: typescript, interface, concatenation, this, semigroup

I'm exploring the Typescript type system by implementing the [Fantasy Land Spec](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land) and I ran into an issue while trying to implement the spec for [Semigroup](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#semigroup).

The spec stipulates that a `Semigroup` should adhere to the following type definition:

```
concat :: Semigroup a => a ~> a -> a
```

I understand this to mean that a type `a`, which implements `Semigroup`, should have a `concat` method that takes in a parameter of type `a` and returns a parameter of type `a`.

The only way I could think of expressing this type definition in TypeScript is this:

```
interface Semigroup {
    concat(other: this): this;
}
```

But when I try to implement this interface on a class, like this:

```
class Sum implements Semigroup {
    constructor(readonly num: number) {}

    concat(other: Sum): Sum {
        return new Sum(this.num + other.num);
    }
}
```

I get a compiler error telling me that:

```sh
Property 'concat' in type 'Sum' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Semigroup'.
  Type '(other: Sum) => Sum' is not assignable to type '(other: this) => this'.
    Type 'Sum' is not assignable to type 'this'.
      'Sum' is assignable to the constraint of type 'this', but 'this' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Sum'.(2416)
```

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505560/how-to-fix-ts2322-could-be-instantiated-with-a-different-subtype-of-constraint) S/O answer, I think I understand the problem.

I think the compiler is essentially telling me: your interface says that you should be taking a parameter that is of the concrete type `this` (`Sum` in this particular case), but a class that extends `Sum` could also be passed in.

However, I don't know how to fix it. That is, I don't know how to express the type definition for `Semigroup` in TypeScript. How to reference the implementing class from an interface?

Here is a [link](https://tsplay.dev/NDz41W) to a TS Playground.

#### Update

@Guerric P's answer made me think of a partial solution. Guerric's solution was to use a generic on the interface. This solution makes *implementing* the `Semigroup` spec possible, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mqQdZm), but the interface doesn't really enforce it.

The fantasy land further describes the spec as follows:

```
s.concat(b)

/** 
 * `b` must be a value of the same `Semigroup`
 *
 * If `b` is not the same semigroup, behaviour of `concat` is 
 * unspecified.
 *
 * `concat` must return a value of the same `Semigroup`.
 */
```

Instead of making `b` a generic, I figured that we could at least restrict the type to `Semigroup`. That way it enforces the constraint that `b` must be of type `Semigroup` as shown here:

```
interface Semigroup {
    concat(other: Semigroup): Semigroup;
}
```

But it still doesn't enforce that it must be of the SAME `Semigroup`. I'm still looking for a way to do that with the TypeScript type system.

Answer (score 2):

I don't want to question your interpretation of that fantasy-land spec, which I admit I don't fully understand, so I'll assume your interpretation is right .

The problem is that your `class` could be extended, so `this` could refer to that extended class. There is no such thing as `final class` or equivalent in TypeScript.

Now let's suppose you have an `ExtendedSum` class which extends `Sum`. Your `equals` implementation still works because `(other: Sum) => boolean` is assignable to `(other: ExtendedSum) => boolean`. Indeed, a function that takes a `Sum` as parameter can take an `ExtendedSum` as well (structural typing principle).

However, your `concat` implementation doesn't work because `(other: Sum) => Sum` is not assignable to `(other: ExtendedSum) => ExtendedSum`. Indeed, a function that returns a `Sum` is not assignable to a function that returns an `ExtendedSum` because a `Sum` is **not necessarily** an `ExtendedSum`.

You could fix that with a generic typed interface:

```
interface Semigroup<T> {
    concat(other: T): T;
}

class Sum implements Setoid, Semigroup<Sum> {
    constructor(readonly num: number) {}

    equals(other: Sum): boolean {
        return this.num === other.num;
    }

    concat(other: Sum): Sum {
        return new Sum(this.num + other.num);
    }
}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.5.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoTAe2AE2QbwFgAoZM5CARwFc4AbAZwApMwALaALmXeAYEpuAI0yY6EOCADcJAL4kSAegBUyksmVoIAW2ABzKJmoAHHgE9jKHBBihgYYJhDJJeOnADuDbmzBhj3oqKevZs1EIAdAiY2orw4HAMZu4gOHGSYIlmALQpOADEDDr6hibqyookoJCwiCjougZGxgA8ACoAfATq5NEgCHBgLOxcyG2CYzLE8sQkCO4MDGjU2sjA2sbi2hDgS+hYuAA0Wo2lragrXUSkvU4MYFDUCFhQTFASOE50ZsggK9x-bRCaD8AgzHpkKi0RjDDhQbgXbQTERiCTOa7kTHId5gahQZy8BgRQHIAC85OQrDhxJWU0x4JuZD6AyGVNGiImiO6jKxOLxzhAEA8y20TEJNNWAGpKSMoBL+HTyDMGSQQHBtgxjHUtAccG0IPduZi+oa4GTfkKRUwAEwKiHIE1gZBCc2C4WIm12nmOh2uy0e21Te0m1EROiYPRMOARKH0ZhwfjHADk+2weHeMHEAA9gAA3exmJNe413UPhyPR2MwoSg8mk50xmhxqOJ5ApjBp5BJbTbB6F4u3EAMMsRqON6HMGvIABk04bVeYCFBAH4XOPm0vkNwAISVpswpfJ1O4HhQSQMex5gtFuQKYhqjVapAnErNfWGjGD01+90rT2Kpk7idF16zdK1A2DIDfVA-0-wg2ZvVLcQw1HaNmUGJgayiJwWSYJd1xhNCcIwyJ0KGJd+FbdtTmaFxFkwBBgEGK8wH7KRkCCOjh0Y5j81YuQgA)

Comment: This would make the correct implementation of the Semigroup type possible, but it wouldn't enforce its contract. With such an interface it would be possible to do 
`class Sum implements Semigroup<Date> {
    concat(other: Date)
}
`
https://tsplay.dev/NVgpqm

Comment: But this made me think of a slightly better, though not perfect, solution. We can at least restrict the type of `T` to `Semigroup`.
https://tsplay.dev/WoJEjm