# Next.js GetServerSideProps custom wrapper TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, next.js

I created a wrapper for `GetServerSideProps` SSR function to reduce repetition but I have problem with typing it correctly with TypeScript. Here's the wrapper:

```js
type WithSessionType = <T extends {}>(
  callback: GetServerSideProps<T>
) => GetServerSideProps<{ session: Session | null } & T>

//                                                 v error
const withSession: WithSessionType = (callback) => async (ctx) => {
  const session = await getSession(ctx)
  const result = await callback?.(ctx)
  const props = result && 'props' in result ? result.props : {}
  return {
    ...result,
    props: {
      session,
      ...props,
    },
  }
}
```

The error:

```
Type '(ctx: GetServerSidePropsContext<ParsedUrlQuery, PreviewData>) => Promise<{ props: { session: Session | null; }; redirect: Redirect; } | { ...; } | { ...; }>' is not assignable to type 'GetServerSideProps<{ session: Session | null; } & T, ParsedUrlQuery, PreviewData>'.
  Type 'Promise<{ props: { session: Session | null; }; redirect: Redirect; } | { props: { session: Session | null; }; notFound: true; } | { props: { session: Session | null; }; }>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<GetServerSidePropsResult<{ session: Session | null; } & T>>'.
    Type '{ props: { session: Session | null; }; redirect: Redirect; } | { props: { session: Session | null; }; notFound: true; } | { props: { session: Session | null; }; }' is not assignable to type 'GetServerSidePropsResult<{ session: Session | null; } & T>'.
      Type '{ props: { session: Session | null; }; }' is not assignable to type 'GetServerSidePropsResult<{ session: Session | null; } & T>'.
        Type '{ props: { session: Session | null; }; }' is not assignable to type '{ props: ({ session: Session | null; } & T) | Promise<{ session: Session | null; } & T>; }'.
          Types of property 'props' are incompatible.
            Type '{ session: Session | null; }' is not assignable to type '({ session: Session | null; } & T) | Promise<{ session: Session | null; } & T>'.
              Type '{ session: Session | null; }' is not assignable to type '{ session: Session | null; } & T'.
                Type '{ session: Session | null; }' is not assignable to type 'T'.
                  '{ session: Session | null; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'.ts(2322)
```

Usecase (that works):

```js
export const getServerSideProps = withSession(async () => {
  return {
    props: {
      custom: 'custom string type',
    },
  }
})
```

Here is a **computed** type of `getServerSideProps`:

```js
const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<{
    session: Session | null;
} & {
    custom: string;
}, ParsedUrlQuery, PreviewData>
```

It works fine and even `InferGetServerSidePropsType` infers types correctly but the mentioned error still occurs.

[image: correct auto completion]

Any idea how can I make the TypeScript happy here?
Also looking forward suggestions and tips regarding this kind of wrapper if you have any.

#### UPDATE

I found what is the cause but I don't quite understand why is that.. Turns out it treated this statement as always false even though `props` can exist on this type.
[image]

GetServerSidePropsResult type:

```
export type GetServerSidePropsResult<P> =
  | { props: P | Promise<P> }
  | { redirect: Redirect }
  | { notFound: true }
```

Why is only `redirect` visible on this type and not `props` or `notFound`?

#### UPDATE 2 - I'm losing my mind

[image]

[image]
Why `T` only exist on 2nd?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is described in another question: [How to fix TS2322: "could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'object'"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505560/how-to-fix-ts2322-could-be-instantiated-with-a-different-subtype-of-constraint)

I haven't been able to understand what should be done exactly to make TS happy but I have a workaround which is to cast the returned function instead of declaring the type returned:

```
function withSession<T extends {}>(callback: GetServerSideProps<T>){
  return (async (ctx) => {
    const session = await getSession(ctx)
    const result = await callback?.(ctx)
    const props = result && 'props' in result ? result.props : {}
    return {
      ...result,
      props: {
        session,
        ...props,
      },
    }
  }) as GetServerSideProps<{ session: Session | null } & T>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure but I think the problem is that T could have another definition of session and so the type is not assignable anymore. You could just use `Omit<T,"session">` to exclude session from T or you could write something like `<T extends { session?: Session | null >` instead of `<T extends {}>`

Btw. `{}` In TS in practice means "any non-null value" so you should consider using something like `Record<string| number, any>` instead

( Not tested, written on my phone so there may be mistakes )

Comment: I tried your proposal but I still have an error: 
`Type '{ session: Session | null; }' is not assignable to type 'T | Promise<T>`

Noted the suggestion with `Record`, thanks!

Comment: I'll take a look at it once I am on my PC.