# Why isn't generic assignable to default param in type typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a vue composable that uses modals of type `{ [key: string]: boolean }`. My implement is shown below. However, I always get error as shown below the code. How can I fix this issue. Any information will be much appreciated.

```
export const useTable = <T extends { [key: string]: boolean }>(
  url: string,
  options: { modals: T } = {
    modals: {
      default: false,
      media: false,
    },
  }
) => {}
```

**Error**

```
Type 'Ref<{ default: boolean; media: boolean; }>' is not assignable to type 'T'.
```

[image]

Comment: why are you even using a generic type `T` then you already know all properties and types?

Comment: Basically, you can't have a default value on a generic type that extends from another type, because it restricts the assignment. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59363875/1628790

Comment: It can be extended when the composable is used

Comment: @DicksonAfful If it is extended further, the default value might be incorrect. No?

Comment: @DicksonAfful By extended further here, I mean if `T` would be a subtype of `{ [key: string]: boolean }`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix TS2322: "could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'object'"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505560/how-to-fix-ts2322-could-be-instantiated-with-a-different-subtype-of-constraint)

Comment: There has been an explanation of the issue before (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505560/how-to-fix-ts2322-could-be-instantiated-with-a-different-subtype-of-constraint) but here is a way to maintain your declaration which compiles - perhaps a possible solution:

```typescript
export const useTable = <T extends { [key: string]: boolean }>(
  url: string,
  options: { modals: T | { [key: string]: boolean } } = {
    modals: {
      default: false,
      media: false,
    },
  }
) => {}
```

Comment: URL with the demonstrated solution: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAgMZQHYGdEFd0gCoCGARgDYgIC8CAPHguHCKgCboIDeCA2gNYgCeALgSYYAS1QBzALrCiUKGQKoEAXwB8ACmAIEWGCWGiJkgDQ6EUCHDFp0wzgFsozAiXsI6AHw7c+QkThxKVkEeUUQZTVoqnYLXWdXdwd43QRmEAAzAiwSOGFs9xBzNLTHEGYxAgK3XBK01XrVYABKSnUOZqA