# Typescript error TS2420 with class implementing its interface template parameter

Tags: typescript

The following Typescript:

```
interface IBase
{
    f():void;
}

class CBase<T extends IBase> implements T
{
    f():void
    {
        //logic here
    }
}
```

is giving me an error:

> Class 'CBase' incorrectly implements interface 'T'.
> 'CBase' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'IBase'.

**What condition exactly is the compiler trying to prevent, and how do I work around that?**
What I ultimately want is to have several interfaces (with a common base) with corresponding classes that implement them, but with one underlying set of functionality. Something like this:

```
interface IFoo extends IBase{}
interface IBar extends IBase{}

class CFoo extends CBase<IFoo>{}
class CBar extends CBase<IBar>{}
```

and they all share the same implementation of `f()`, the one in `CBase`, *but* in the way that `IFoo` and `IBar` are not compatible types.

Similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505560/how-to-fix-ts2322-could-be-instantiated-with-a-different-subtype-of-constraint)?

For the record, this object hierarchy works in C++ (modulo lack of template constraints), but doesn't in C#, since you can't derive from generic parameters in C#.

The design goals are:

- specialized class/interface pairs (`IFoo`/`CFoo`) are as minimal as possible - no methods spelled out explicitly in those
- specialized classes and interfaces are in one to one correspondence (so that `IFoo` can be mapped to `CFoo` and nothing else)

Comment: Why do you need to do this instead of "implements IBase"?

Comment: I want to do interface based dependency injection: you need IFoo, you get CFoo.

Comment: I think you are looking for abstract classes, not interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got away with the following:

```
interface IBase
{
    f():void;
}

class CBase implements IBase
{
    f():void
    {
        //Logic here
    }
}
```

And then the specializations:

```
interface IFoo extends IBase{}
class CFoo extends CBase implements IFoo{}
```

So what I have here is a textbook diamond inheritance, but I'm getting away with it because of unavoidably dynamic call dispatch of JavaScript.