# Predefinied generic type options <T = number | string>(): T [TypeScript]

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to define generic type T as predefined by me types. Below simple example can explain exacly what I mean. I need to get a function in which generic type `T` can be only `number | string` and this function should returns `T | undefined`.

```
export const getItemFromLocalStorage = <T extends number | string>(
  key: string,
  type?: 'number' | 'string'
): T | undefined => {
  const storedItem: string | null = localStorage.getItem(key)

  if (_.isNaN(storedItem)) {
    return undefined
  }

  if (_.isEqual(type, 'number')) {
    return _.toNumber(storedItem)
  }

  return _.toString(storedItem)
}
```

This version views an issue:
`'string' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | number'.`. And the same at `_.toNumber` method.

I also tried set `<T = number | string>`.

How can I achieve it with a TypeScript?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You dont need generic at all. See [this](https://tsplay.dev/wepOXW_

Comment: There is an great answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505560/how-to-fix-ts2322-could-be-instantiated-with-a-different-subtype-of-constraint) that explains more in depth this issue you are facing.

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine it looks like a link doesn't work :x