# Typescript - Property does not exist on extended generic interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

**Scenario**: I am attempting to create a base method I can reuse (`works`/`doesNotWork`) for a few different calls I need to make.  The base method should do some setup as I do not want to repeat several times.  The problem is, the generic I am passing to my setup call is telling me it expects a different type.  All the properties I need exist on the base generic type, but I get typescript issues.

**Error**: `Argument of type '{ SyncCount: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DeepPartial<T>'`

**Goal**: I would like a solution using generics which would allow me to have a base method I can call for setup.  Ideally, `doesNotWork` would be modified to work properly.  Aos, please see the desired code (goal) in the example below and in the fiddle.

Here is a fiddle of my [issue](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhFgAoEMBOwCWyA2AeAKgHxQC8U+UEAHsBAHYAmAzlAPYBGAVhAMbBQB+KAG8AsACgoUqAG1EUDHSgBrCCFYAzcgF0BALljwkaTDgJzthANwSAvlAP4b4iYtqoNyHtACSMdgBKvKyoDCIS0lCoEMgMrHTYIFAA+hgMBkzAqIoA5s6R0bHxiSnRAG4ZWbn50oVxCUkwrDwArgC29MD44BCV2XR5dhKudO6e3lA+AEItGNgMEKgEAKKjGKCUNPTMk-5BPCEMxGKS0gueLdjATAAUZTgtvYYIKOhYePirmKCEAJQGMzmCyWnzWPyGLnEPGwyCYLEB80WKzBSWotEYLD8gWCoWIGDaYGwEA6o0xCOByO+IGOw1OUnOyEu1zuDyecBeJnelPW1P+k3JSNBVJpdMiUQgwBaqCUwAAFhgmDUpLZaSrIW5FuNfFNYRAvjzNuidlj9odwqKAMogOg8ADCrBaowMdHa7EWSqgVptFuAyElTD6uQhIzGXl8trQhu2ZN1+o2J0iAFlWAtsIGBs41SHNWHJohFkx4lGMfzYyjzZEAHLIDrpnLBqEwuHkCCZc0RaRgVCsWh8CBhdizREguOorYlk04o43X4VsVSaKS6VQOgQADuUAFI5RhBnHqzoq7GHutCga5CyiYBGLxp1TD1O5nc-nAHoXyue1AWkxclA5dAcnoRYMB4P8ejPC8mA7edFylGV5SYAA6QcgSRaYy2FGdEIZJlbmET1rTtB0nSgAAGKBbF+aCKNpSIjxPaA4lbSsewAdQva80WjUt71HXdZwTecoDfL8fwGP9ZQAoDslA0BICgJiWDoT9z1QZRqIKCU4IkhVkKHCkiCwnCrjwgibXtR1gAMcjKOog86OyBioELDp2LU3IfAJbASV9TB4k48dbwwnl+OfMVYOXOVdJQ4cCH47CIAuEybnwr0iMs6yKN+fdaOkESfDPZBRj-VgoGQMpWDSBSWkJEC-WgA4FigN1sFYDcNG7NoFMSxkTMQ6iRIAQWa3VnK0sAoA6OUUwgy4B2gN1MmoyBWEJaAyCipCYopHx81QQs6Hi4zmVSwiLJImzsuong0BYDaEL01Clh8CNUCOnrcJSsz0ourLnAG98AHEAHlBoAGWo5IVrW0gdKQlyIDc5QPK8ny-QwfzdoLeJ+I9ZIbv22HNsQhGkZRwk0b8uhcBetBcbsIA)

```js
type DeepPartial<T> = T extends object ? {
    [P in keyof T]?: DeepPartial<T[P]>;
} : T;

interface IDbRecord {
    readonly _id: string;
    readonly _rev: string;
    readonly DocumentType: string;
}

interface IBuilder<TEntity extends IDbRecord> {
    defaults(value: DeepPartial<TEntity>): Builder<TEntity>
}

class Builder<TEntity extends IDbRecord> implements IBuilder<TEntity> {

    defaults(value: DeepPartial<TEntity>): IBuilder<TEntity> {
        return this;
    }

}

interface IBaseEntity extends IDbRecord {
    SyncCount: number;
    SyncStatus: string
}

interface ICar extends IBaseEntity {
    Model: string;
}

interface IPerson extends IBaseEntity {
    Name: string
}

class Test {

    protected builder<TEntity extends IDbRecord>() {
        return new Builder<TEntity>();
    }

    private works<T extends IBaseEntity>() {
        // not using the generic type works
        return this.builder<IBaseEntity>().defaults({ SyncCount: 0 })
    }

    private doesNotWork<T extends IBaseEntity>() {
        // using the generic type does not work here
        return this.builder<T>().defaults({ SyncCount: 0 }) // ERROR
    }

    private someWorkingImplmentation<T extends IBaseEntity>() {
        return this.builder<T>().defaults({ SyncCount: 0 });
    }

    // I want to avoid duplicate code below from defaults.
    // A base setup method would be best
    people = this.builder<IPerson>().defaults({ SyncCount: 0 });
    cars = this.builder<ICar>().defaults({ SyncCount: 0 });

    // GOAL
    _people = this.someWorkingImplmentation<IPerson>();
    _cars = this.someWorkingImplmentation<ICar>();
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for an explanation of why or a solution? I have solutions but don't have a concrete description of why and documentation to point to as my source.

Comment: I can solve it by `return this.builder<T>().defaults({ SyncCount: 0 } as DeepPartial<T>)`.

Comment: Updated the goal @ug_.  I would like a solution :)

Comment: what kind of solution? because the solution could be to not use the generic, i dont know what you want :/

Comment: Updated the goal @kelly, I would like to use generics in the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type restriction in `doesNotWork<T extends IBaseEntity>` doesn't seem to propagate down to the method `defaults`. This seems to cause Typescript to think that the generic T could be anything, despite it being constrained to `IBaseEntity`. See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505560/how-to-fix-ts2322-could-be-instantiated-with-a-different-subtype-of-constraint) for more detail.

Right now the constraints flow as such

```
doesNotWork<ICar> // return type inferred from builder<T>
  builder<T> - this is where the constraints of IBaseEntity fall off
    defaults<T>()
```

One simple solution is to invert the constraint by fixing your return type of the function:

```
private doesNotWork<T extends IBaseEntity>(): IBuilder<T> {
    return this.builder<IBaseEntity>().defaults({ SyncCount: 0 })
}
```

By adding the return type of `IBuilder<T>` we are removing the requirement of generic `T` flowing through to the builder to determine our return type.

---

With this the following code now properly recognizes the fields of the interface:

```
_people = this.works<IPerson>().defaults({ Name: 'Foo' });
_cars = this.works<ICar>().defaults({ Model: 'jetta' });
```

Comment: Using your example I am able to get solution to work.  My real world solution is a bit more complex, the fiddle is meant to be a simpler explanation of the issue.  Nonetheless, I am able to get my complex solution to work.  It is a bit odd why the constraints fall off.  The properties exist on type `T`, but aren't accessible.  Anyways, this is what I needed!  Thank you!!!