# TS2322 : Type is both not assignable and assignable error, what does that mean?

Tags: typescript, generics

I am trying to wrap my head around this. I have been working with generics in Java and C#, but only recently in TypeScript. So, can someone please explain to me this madness?

> constructor FooAdapter(): FooAdapter
>
> Type 'FooAdapter' is not assignable to type 'A'.
>
> 'FooAdapter' is assignable to the constraint of type 'A', but 'A' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'FooAdapter'.
>
> ts(2322)

From the following snippet:

```
interface IFoo {}

interface IAdapter<F extends IFoo> {
   getFoo():F
}

abstract class AbstractFoo<F extends IFoo> {
   abstract something<A extends IAdapter<F>>():A;
}


class Foo implements IFoo {}
class FooAdapter implements IAdapter<Foo> {
   getFoo() { return new Foo(); }
}

class FooFactory extends AbstractFoo<Foo> {
   something<A extends FooAdapter>():A {
      return new FooAdapter();  // <--- ts(2322) here
   }   
}
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix TS2322: "could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'object'"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505560/how-to-fix-ts2322-could-be-instantiated-with-a-different-subtype-of-constraint)

Comment: I also changed your code to show why it's a problem (line 28): https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDED2nkG8C+AUIaJLIiqgIIAmcADmQDzrIQAekINAzmlpgB8eQsjEBzCGAEAKAJQAudISKE4AIx5goiMMgQAbODz5VN23QJZtOEbnwzZhuUWI1adCPT0wBbKQAWoOJMVDZcvGi0DMzogoLyClQA3CrEhIbGfALIwL70BhD+4A45BBlGJsgC0YzQufmFxWAOtbFOImLIktLY8njIUFIArlAgyCAQAO7VfXLJyESqmVUAQlJkNXR1UOF2kVsx9S5iCHAGBgCyEInIAG6YwDR4S8Qr2djouphQAJ579mQZg8lmwLA6JzEPn8YCCIBCYQ4EQ+mDa0ASijCkK6gxGYwm01mqO2ZHkC2QAHoKcgmABaenIFoyABMAGZmcy5MgAtAIK5Fl00hlMCAtMgYMgALwEmYCL5eH6-MnC0V6YYBADyASl4oAdNDAsEmOswJtsGioBjkkA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `FooAdapter` is not `A`, `FooAdapter` may only be the parent class of `A`.

Your options here are:

A) Make `something`'s return more generic so that it is happy with `new FooAdapter()`:

```
interface IFoo {}

interface IAdapter<F extends IFoo> {
   getFoo():F
}

abstract class AbstractFoo<F extends IFoo> {
   abstract something(): IAdapter<F>;
}


class Foo implements IFoo {}

class FooAdapter implements IAdapter<Foo> {
   getFoo() { return new Foo(); }
}

interface IHasEmptyConstructor<T> {
    new(): T
}

class FooFactory extends AbstractFoo<Foo> {
   something(): IAdapter<Foo> {
      return new FooAdapter();
   }   
}

const fooFactory = new FooFactory();

fooFactory.something();
```

B) Make `something` return `A` instead of `FooAdapter`:

```
interface IFoo {}

interface IAdapter<F extends IFoo> {
   getFoo():F
}

abstract class AbstractFoo<F extends IFoo> {
   abstract something<A extends IAdapter<F>>(adapter: IHasEmptyConstructor<A>):A;
}


class Foo implements IFoo {}

class FooAdapter implements IAdapter<Foo> {
   getFoo() { return new Foo(); }
}

interface IHasEmptyConstructor<T> {
    new(): T
}

class FooFactory extends AbstractFoo<Foo> {
   something<A extends FooAdapter>(adapter: IHasEmptyConstructor<A>): A {
      return new adapter();
   }   
}

const fooFactory = new FooFactory();

fooFactory.something(FooAdapter);
```

Comment: OK, so if I understand, then `something<A extends FooAdapter>():A` must return something extending `FooAdapter`, but **must not be** `FooAdapter`, is that it?

Comment: It must return `A` and `A` is a generic (mystery type). The inference does not know that `FooAdapter`  is `A`, it could be but it also might not be as demonstrated by @zerkms on line 28 of the snippet. It only knows that `A` should extend `FooAdapater`, so all the properties / methods from `FooAdapter` should be available to use withing `something`.