# Why can't the return type of document.createElement be assigned to a generic that's restricted to HTMLElement?

Tags: javascript, typescript, domdocument, jsdoc, createelement

I'm writing a `clone(el)` function that must accept an `HTMLElement` or subtype, and should return the exact same type that it's given.

How can I write this function's generic signature to be correct please? Thanks!

Is no.2 where I'm going wrong, in how `T` is being restricted to `HTMLElement`?

---

To be precise, I'm writing plain JavaScript and using JSDoc in VS Code, which offers a [`@template` definition to define a generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#template):

1. define a generic `T`
2. restrict `T` to `HTMLElement` or subtypes thereof
3. define both the first parameter and return type as the generic `T`
4. use `document.createElement(tagName: string)` which returns type `HTMLElement`
5. make sure the return type of `createElement` is type `T` – I, the author, know it will be, because creating an element with the same tagName will always result in the same type of element, but `createElement` doesn't know this because it doesn't know specifically what value `el.tagName` is, it only knows it's of type `string`.

```js
/**
 * @template {HTMLElement} T
 * @param {T} el
 * @returns {T}
 */
function clone(el) {
    /** @type {T} */
    const newEl = document.createElement(el.tagName);
    //    ^^^^^ Error from above appears on this

    // do copying of attributes and child nodes
    return newEl;
}
```

I believe this to be the same result in TypeScript:

```js
function clone<T extends HTMLElement>(el: T): T {
    const newEl: T = document.createElement(el.tagName);
    // do copying of attributes and child nodes
    return newEl;
}
```

[View on TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBANggpgHgCqPQDynTABMBnRACWwFkAZAURXQFtioA+ACnRQC5E2AJQDcAbwBQiacgRkoiMOgDuTUYgC8iEnAgg2YKADoIAJ3QBDIk1bseKI1AsBzAHIW2QgNxSZAej9tOFkABwBPGDBnRDhgRCsoUxgAIxAiCgtSZAALGBQSRTgSdDJfaXMoEFMkJVUUHwBfIA)

However, TypeScript complains that

> Type 'HTMLElement' is not assignable to type 'T'.
>
> 'HTMLElement' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'HTMLElement'. (2322)

---

The error makes sense to me, because if I rewrite it for a specific example, I get the same error, but more understandable:

```js
function clone<T extends HTMLElement>(el: T): T {
    return document.createElement('input');
}
```

[View in TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBANggpgHgCqPQDynTABMBnRACWwFkAZAURXQFtioA+ACnRQC5E2AJQDcAbwBQiaYgBO6KCFlIScCCDZgoAOgjyAhkSat2XAOQwwABxBQzQgNwSAvkA)

> Type 'HTMLInputElement' is not assignable to type 'T'.
>
> 'HTMLInputElement' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'HTMLElement'. (2322)

I've tried to read the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/59363875 but I feel like, in my case, I'm more restricted because `document.createElement` is defining its type signature as `Document.createElement(tagName: string, options?: ElementCreationOptions | undefined): HTMLElement`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're experiencing is because document.createElement returns an HTMLElement, which is a supertype of the type parameter T. This means that the return is not guaranteed to have the same type as el, and therefore you get a type error when trying to assign it to a variable of type T.

Your final function is fairly close, you just need to make the return as type T.

```
function clone<T extends HTMLElement>(el: T): T {
    const newEl = document.createElement(el.tagName);
    return newEl as T;
}
```

or more succinctly

```
function clone<T extends HTMLElement>(el: T): T {
    return document.createElement(el.tagName) as T;
}
```