# How to resolve 'X' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'X' in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have [this TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAgGYFcB2BjOBLKaHYDOAQgDYogA8AKguHCGgCaEICyIhAFgHwAUwBAigAjAFYgsALgToA1migB3NABpBCOAE8IIGbQA+CAIIwYAQy00e6gJQzRErAVZkKAOShMQ1HVWo8CADeGhh4hIjmZpYyphZWAQgAvCbRWgB0RHGWfNq6tggA-Jp+CDIA2nkgALoaMCBwKDD4AkJCjpKIAIQpaCikpAgAZEMlulBIwuKdyUkpAOQdWPPDQxpC81Ur2PhLiCPrYyATU05w6VWzCxEwOwDmKwdtCFHxmZjk3oR8fHsvruQQJ5vL5dNZbBc-LYNNCAL7AUCQWCIRgoAC27E4XGCGmMhEIIHguHwCzRWIAtOZ8YScHh5up4YjoPAjgg3CBiFSfKUUiEhGFSLAZPMRID5sBGeBmYhLuy8QSiXhQSBkmzAZyCcrhjihFUZBxuOl5TTiRKEVLkaz2WxzBAIPctbyNPMydxKdTFWh5jI5R7aWhlWamZbZYDgdywbR6IwWJjuIEUtbbfa0HdleVqNUgA):

```
export function isBlue<T extends Mesh>(
  object: unknown,
  type: T | Array<T>,
): object is BlueNodeType<T> {
  const array: Array<T> = Array.isArray(type) ? type : [type]
  return (
    object != null && typeof object === 'object' &&
    'type' in object &&
    typeof object.type === 'string' &&
    array.includes((object as BlueNodeType<T>).type)
  )
}

export enum Mesh {
  Assertion = 'mesh-assertion',
}

export type BlueBaseType = {
  color: 'blue'
}

export type BlueAssertionType = BlueBaseType & {
  type: Mesh.Assertion
}

export type BlueMappingType = {
  'mesh-assertion': BlueAssertionType
}

export type BlueNodeType<T extends Mesh> = BlueMappingType[T]
```

It is throwing this error:

```
Argument of type 'Mesh' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
  'Mesh' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Mesh'.(2345)
```

How do I get this to work? In my real codebase I have a `BlueMappingType` with 40 types, so I would like for it to be able to pick the correct type based on the generic type parameter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix TS2322: "could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'object'"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505560/how-to-fix-ts2322-could-be-instantiated-with-a-different-subtype-of-constraint)

Comment: Nope, I can't figure it out from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Array.prototype.includes` is tricky one. In order to make it work, you can try my custom `includes`:

```js
const withTuple = <
  List extends string[]
>(list: readonly [...List]) =>
  (prop: string): prop is List[number] =>
    list.includes(prop)

export function isBlue<T extends Mesh>(
  object: unknown,
  type: T | Array<T>,
): object is BlueNodeType<T> {
  const array: Array<T> = Array.isArray(type) ? type : [type]
  const includes = withTuple(array)
  return (
    object != null && typeof object === 'object' &&
    'type' in object &&
    typeof object.type === 'string' &&
    includes(object.type)
  )
}

export enum Mesh {
  Assertion = 'mesh-assertion',
}

export type BlueBaseType = {
  color: 'blue'
}

export type BlueAssertionType = BlueBaseType & {
  type: Mesh.Assertion
}

export type BlueMappingType = {
  'mesh-assertion': BlueAssertionType
}

export type BlueNodeType<T extends Mesh> = BlueMappingType[T]
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mL5eAW)

`withTuple` is just a curried version of `Array.prototype.includes` but it works with tuples.

You can check my [article](https://catchts.com/useful-patterns#includes) for more examples