# Using a default parameter that is a subtype of the generic type passed in?

Tags: typescript

I have this kind of code:

```js
type MapOf<V> = { [key: string]: V };

type ThingWithConfigCallback<ThingType, ConfigType extends MapOf<any>> = (
  Thing: ThingType,
  config?: ConfigType,
) => void;

type ThingWithConfig<ThingType, ConfigType extends MapOf<any>> = {
  Thing: ThingType,
  config?: ConfigType,
};

const createThingsWithConfig <T, C>() => {
  const registerThingsWithConfig: ThingWithConfigCallback<T, C> = (Thing: T, config: C) => {
  // do stuff to register things
  }
  // other functions
  return {
    registerThingsWithConfig,
    // other functions
  }
};
```

However I want to provide a default parameter for config for `registerThingsWithConfig`, instead of leaving it undefined. However I can't create a default that's of the correct type/subtype.

If I do `(Thing: T, config: C = {}) => {` I get `Type '{}' is not assignable to C` and how `Type '{}' is assignable to the constraint of 'C', but 'C' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'MapOf<any>'`

If I declare `const defaultConfig: MapOf<any> = {};` and use that as the default param in `registerThingsWithConfig` I get the same error but with `Type MapOf<any> is assignable to the constraint of 'C' ...`

But I do not follow how/why that is the case, even after reading [How to fix TS2322: "could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'object'"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505560/how-to-fix-ts2322-could-be-instantiated-with-a-different-subtype-of-constraint) .

Comment: Personally I would use an `as` assertion.  I don't think there's any way around it.

Comment: It's an error because you don't know for sure what `C` is, and `C` could *theoretically* have some required properties and therefore `{}` would not be assignable to that `C`.  Example: `const x = createThingsWithConfig<string, { hello: 'world' }>(); x.registerThingsWithConfig('text');`.

Comment: @LindaPaiste your examples is amazingly clear to me. Thank you. Please do put that in an answer so I can upvote it and mark it as correct