# Process object properties of certain type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to apply a transformation function `(dt: Date) => Date` to all given `Date` properties of an object. I think I'm close but still stuck. Note that I'm trying to do it as type-safely as possible.

What I have so far is:

```js
const transform = (dt: Date) => dt;

function process<T extends { [k in K]: Date }, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, ...props: K[]) {
    props.forEach(p => (obj[p] = transform(obj[p])));
}
```

The problem with the above `process` function is that it's failing in the assignment `obj[p] = transformDate(obj[p])` part saying that:

> Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'T[K]'.

But at the same time it seems to recognize `T[K]` is a `Date` as it doesn't complain with `transform(obj[p])`.

How can I update the above function to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works, when you use `getDate` and `setDate` instead of direct assigning. Depends whenever this is usable for your case. It can do basically the same thing, but it is little bit less readable.

```
const transform = (dt: Date) => dt;

function process<T extends { [k in K]: Date }, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, ...props: K[]) {
  for (let key of props) {
    let transformed = transform(obj[key])
    obj[key].setDate(transformed.getDate())
  }
}
```

I think the problem is more described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59363875/21775425) (*Cause 1*) to somewhat similar question.

You can also cast the date object, like this:

```
const transform = (dt: Date) => dt;

function process<F extends Date, T extends { [k in K]: F }, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, ...props: K[]) {
  for (let key of props) {
    obj[key] = <T[K]> transform(obj[key])
  }
}
```

This should still remain type safe.

Comment: Yes, I finally ended up casting the `transform`'s result - thanks for the link you left above ;)