# How to fix `'...' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '...'. (2322)

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

### Problem - [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAQwM4E8B2BjOAzArpmASwjUSSUIHM0A5XAWwCNgoAeAKDjgBU5QZgaACZI4AJWAZoQ1khhRCaSgBo4aBsygA+ZZzgBpPiAHDRAa2AoI2Hrq0AKPREYArSTABctvRZRf9ugCUcADeTq7uANq+ALpwALxwACwATADccAD0mXCAMuR8UFDQPChgwHAA5OpMLBVwhKJoEPDIFNQIjAA25TAQcDCl5RXckfoxFewAvkA)

I'm trying to dynamically assign a number to an object based on its shape.

```
export async function assignNumber<
  T extends Record<string, number>,
  K extends keyof T,
>(
  object: T,
  key: K,
) {
  object[key] = 42; // ❌ error Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'T[K]'
}
```

Error

```
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'T[K]'.
  'number' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T[K]', but 'T[K]' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'number'.(2322)
```

#### Minimal Reproducible Example - [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABACwKYBt1wDwBVGoAeUqYAJgM6IVQBOMYA5gHwAUAthYwFyK4CUiAN4AoRIk6NEAXkQByAO5xa6MnMQB6DYkAy5HwCeAB1Tya9JuphUwcKIgCGFCjEZh7AI3QmocRFCMmcrjqIgC+IiIQCDQoMLxyyDDqsglJEVqIgKDkiAByvqi0tMoOVP7G8omWVPbUIO5lJnDA1HQMjAB0Ihl6AEIgdhTIcCCqYHJ27iaOzq4OYPpQiUwE6BTeyPZIqXIiaJhwrImCQA)

After reading this [great answer explaining in detail the error *"could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59363875/7017689), I came up with this:

```
function hello<T extends string>(msg: T) {
  msg = 'world' // ❌ Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T' 
}

const hi: 'hi' = 'hi'

// ✅ No error as type 'hi' is a subtype of string.
// ❌ But shouldn't be assign anything else than 'hi'
hello(hi)
```

Error

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'string' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string'.(2322)
```

### Solution ? - [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAQwM4E8B2BjOAzArpmASwjUSSUIHM0A5XAWwCNgoAeAKDjgBU5QZgaACZI4AJWAZoQ1khhRCaSgBo4aBsygA+ZZzgBpPiAHDRAa2AoI2Hrq0AKPREYArSTABctvRZRf97ACUcADeTq7uANq+ALpwALxwACwATGQ8kfoxANxwAPR5cADKEAA2uEQkXIkABsgZWTVwgMrk7AC+QA)

```
export async function assignNumber<
  T extends Record<string, number>,
  K extends keyof T,
>(
  object: T,
  key: K
) {
  object[key] = 42 as T[K]; // Solution  = `as T[K]` ❓
}
```

Is it a TypeScript limitation due to a loose interpretation of type contstraints in generics ?

In otherwords, because subtypes also satisfy the constraint an error may occur ? ("*could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint*")

How would you manage this error ?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Found this https://tsplay.dev/w8Vx0m