# Infer function argument type based on default value

Tags: typescript

I would like to infer a type based on the default value provided.

I have the following code:

```js
type Foo = {
  bar: string
}

const variable: Foo = {
  bar: "string..."
}

const func = (arg: <T extends Record<string, any>>(state: T) => T) => arg
```

When I try to run `func`, I get an error:

```js
func((state = variable) => state) // Type 'Foo' is not assignable to type 'T'.
```

Why is this error appearing, and why can't I infer the type of `state` to be of type `Foo`?

Please see playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFKAjAhgJwC4oBnYfASwDsBzdAX3XQGM4qyoA3Ai3bAGwjF4iFBix4iUAERlKtAHRLpDJq3bAoAMwCuVZsigAKAjWIAeACpQIAD2AQqAExJQAShFb4n5udRoANFC4VCAAfGFGZLgOxJYAlMhhUAlJwfh06Lr6RlHAMdAo3JR8golIydEOiQD0NVDmALSNUADuABYgUBSuoJBQAOQiA92uVHCauCQkFDRUpdDAiH3QA5YDAPxAA).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix TS2322: "could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'object'"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505560/how-to-fix-ts2322-could-be-instantiated-with-a-different-subtype-of-constraint)

Comment: TL;DR you can't use a concrete type in a generic context like that. Just [move the generic declaration to the outer function and pass the type parameter explicitly rather than relying on inference.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFKAjAhgJwC4oBnYfASwDsBzdAX3XQGM4qyoA3Ai3bAGwjF4iFBix4iUAERlKtAHRLpDJq3bAoAMwCuVZsigAeACpQIAD2AQqAExJQAShFb5bRudRoAaKLiogAHyBABQENIQhZLjWxCYAlMiBUAlJfvh06Lr6RiKhUcAx0CjclHyCiUjJ0daJAPR1xgC0TVAA7gAWIFAUDqCQUADkIoM9DlRwmrgkJBQ0VOXQwIj90IMmgwD8QA)

Answer (score -2):

The error message "Type 'Foo' is not assignable to type 'T'" is occurring because TypeScript is not able to infer the type of T when you call the func function. In your code, variable is of type Foo, but TypeScript doesn't know if T should be inferred as Foo in this context.

To fix this error and specify that T should be Foo, you can explicitly specify the generic type when calling the func function like this:

`func<Foo>((state = variable) => state);`

By using , you are telling TypeScript that T should be of type Foo, and now passing variable to the function is valid because they both have the same type.
--by GPT3.5

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1